# Cannot VBA write data to cells in Excel 2007/2010 within a function

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2010, vba

I want to set value for cells by VBA. I have googled, and see some resolution:

```
Sheets("SheetName").Range("A1").value = someValue
Sheets("SheetName").Cells(1,1).value = someValue
```

With this kind of code, I can just read data from cell A1 but I cannot set a new value to it.

*Update*

The code to set cell A1 value is put within a `Function` as below.

```
Function abb()
    Sheets("SheetName").Range("A1").value = 122333
    abb = 'any thing'
End Function
```

In cell B2, I set `=abb()` and hit enter. I get #VALUE but nothing happen at A1.

Putting this code in a macro, it works.

My question is, how to make A1 have values within a function?

Comment: You have two choices. Either run it as a Subroutine, or use the UDF timer workaround from http://stackoverflow.com/q/8520732/641067. The former is easier.

Comment: If you want a function return something in A1, then the function call should be entered in A1. That is the way Excel works.

Comment: Why don't you trap ths change to B2 with a sheet change event then populate A1? From your code the function will not be updating as it doesn't have any arguments.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From your comment above you wanted to try this approach

If you enter
`=abb()`
into any cell

Then cell A1 of that sheet wil be set to 12333

This is the line to update to pick the cell to update, and to place a value in it
`Range("A1").Value = 122333`

From [I don't want my Excel Add-In to return an array (instead I need a UDF to change other cells)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8520732/641067)

> I am reposting this piece of magic from [Kevin Jones aka Zorvek](https://mvp.support.microsoft.com/profile=7E428211-E8AB-4F68-AEB1-FDD5C3DB5433) as it sits [behind the EE Paywall](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/Q_22095686.html) (link attached if anyone has access)
>
> While Excel strictly forbids a UDF from changing any cell, worksheet,
>   or workbook properties, there is a way to effect such changes when a
>   UDF is called using a Windows timer and an Application.OnTime timer in
>   sequence. The Windows timer has to be used within the UDF because
>   Excel ignores any Application.OnTime calls inside a UDF. But, because
>   the Windows timer has limitations (Excel will instantly quit if a
>   Windows timer tries to run VBA code if a cell is being edited or a
>   dialog is open), it is used only to schedule an Application.OnTime
>   timer, a safe timer which Excel only allows to be fired if a cell is
>   not being edited and no dialogs are open.
>
> The example code below illustrates how to start a Windows timer from
>   inside a UDF, how to use that timer routine to start an
>   Application.OnTime timer, and how to pass information known only to
>   the UDF to subsequent timer-executed routines. The code below must be
>   placed in a regular module.

```
Declare Function SetTimer Lib "user32" ( _
      ByVal HWnd As Long, _
      ByVal nIDEvent As Long, _
      ByVal uElapse As Long, _
      ByVal lpTimerFunc As Long _
   ) As Long

Private Declare Function KillTimer Lib "user32" ( _
      ByVal HWnd As Long, _
      ByVal nIDEvent As Long _
   ) As Long

Private mCalculatedCells As Collection
Private mWindowsTimerID As Long
Private mApplicationTimerTime As Date

Public Function abb()

' This is a UDF that returns the sum of two numbers and starts a windows timer
' that starts a second Appliction.OnTime timer that performs activities not
' allowed in a UDF. Do not make this UDF volatile, pass any volatile functions
' to it, or pass any cells containing volatile formulas/functions or
' uncontrolled looping will start.

   abb = "Whatever you want"

   ' Cache the caller's reference so it can be dealt with in a non-UDF routine
   If mCalculatedCells Is Nothing Then Set mCalculatedCells = New Collection
   On Error Resume Next
   mCalculatedCells.Add Application.Caller, Application.Caller.Address
   On Error GoTo 0

   ' Setting/resetting the timer should be the last action taken in the UDF
   If mWindowsTimerID <> 0 Then KillTimer 0&, mWindowsTimerID
   mWindowsTimerID = SetTimer(0&, 0&, 1, AddressOf AfterUDFRoutine1)

End Function

Public Sub AfterUDFRoutine1()

' This is the first of two timer routines. This one is called by the Windows
' timer. Since a Windows timer cannot run code if a cell is being edited or a
' dialog is open this routine schedules a second safe timer using
' Application.OnTime which is ignored in a UDF.

   ' Stop the Windows timer
   On Error Resume Next
   KillTimer 0&, mWindowsTimerID
   On Error GoTo 0
   mWindowsTimerID = 0

   ' Cancel any previous OnTime timers
   If mApplicationTimerTime <> 0 Then
      On Error Resume Next
      Application.OnTime mApplicationTimerTime, "AfterUDFRoutine2", , False
      On Error GoTo 0
   End If

   ' Schedule timer
   mApplicationTimerTime = Now
   Application.OnTime mApplicationTimerTime, "AfterUDFRoutine2"

End Sub

Public Sub AfterUDFRoutine2()

' This is the second of two timer routines. Because this timer routine is
' triggered by Application.OnTime it is safe, i.e., Excel will not allow the
' timer to fire unless the environment is safe (no open model dialogs or cell
' being edited).

   Dim Cell As Range

   ' Do tasks not allowed in a UDF...
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
   Do While mCalculatedCells.Count > 0
      Set Cell = mCalculatedCells(1)
      mCalculatedCells.Remove 1
      Range("A1").Value = 122333
   Loop
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   End Sub
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett I agree. I was staggered that someone was able conceive of then execute this. Although it does show the danger of "it can't be done".

Comment: my gosh +1 but i'd rather stick to the rules that you cannot do it

Answer (score 7):

You cannot change cell A1 with a function in B2.

Visit: [Description of limitations of custom functions in Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/170787)
.  The text includes:

"A user-defined function called by a formula in a worksheet cell cannot change the environment of Microsoft Excel. This means that such a function cannot do any of the following:

- Insert, delete, or format cells on the spreadsheet.
- **Change another cell's value.**  [My highlighting]
- Move, rename, delete, or add sheets to a workbook.
- Change any of the environment options, such as calculation mode or screen views.
- Add names to a workbook.
- Set properties or execute most methods."

Why do you want to change cell A1 in this way?  Explain your objective and perhaps someone can help.

Comment: It can actually be done, but it is complex. see http://stackoverflow.com/q/8520732/641067

Comment: @brettdj. I missed this question and your answer which is very interesting. However, this is not a technique I would wish to recommend to a newbie.  I think this is a case of the questioner telling us how he thinks his problem can be solved rather than what his problem is.  I want to know why he want a function in B2 to change A1?

Comment: @TonyDallimore i want cache value. Assume i calculate sum of very many cell `Range(B1:B1000)`, i want cache this sum value to A1 (or any cell), so i reopen excel file, excel doesn't need recalculate

Comment: @brettdj i have read (http://stackoverflow.com/q/8520732/641067) , but i don't know how to call `AfterUDFRoutine2` with arguments?

Comment: @Davuz.  You want to cache the result of a complex calculation so the complex calculation is not repeated.  You will need some system of (1) knowing the complex calculation is required, (2) performing it and saving the result and (3) stopping it from happening again.  You also need this system to be better than Excel's system for controlling recalculation.  Having you tried timing the recalculation?  How much time do you want to save and how frequently?

Comment: @TonyDallimore Thank you! i think i have the answer from `brettdj`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to modify two cells with one formula, you may want to consider returning an array from your function. Here's an example:

```
Function abb()
    Dim arr As Variant
    ReDim arr(1 To 2)
    arr(1) = "aardvark"
    arr(2) = "bee"
    abb = arr
End Function
```

Select cells A2 to B2. Type `=abb()` and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to specify that it is an array formula. This formula then modifies both cells (A2 and B2) at the same time.

Perhaps you can customise this to do what you want.

Answer (score -1):

it should work - try this

1. Open a new excel sheet
2. Create a new macro
3. Add this `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value2 = "value"`

you can use both `.Value` and `.Value2`, make sure that the sheet name is correct.

Comment: when i debug, i got stop at statement  "Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value2 = ". I don't know why?

Comment: What is the name of the sheet, if its not `Sheet1` then the issue will come.. try this instead `Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value`, the index will help in finding the correct sheet, once this works you can replace the index with the actual sheet name.

Comment: @Davuz: What do you mean by "got stop"? Does it throw any error? Is the workbook opened readonly?

Comment: @shahkalpesh when i debug, it was run to that statement and throw exception (maybe...) and in excel output "#VALUE"

Comment: say `MsgBox someValue` this will say what the msgbox contains.. if the  excel cell is getting updated then the statement `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value2=someValue` is working...

Comment: @AnanthaSharma oh, i put  `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value2=someValue` in **Sub** and calling by press F8, it's work. but if call this **Sub** in another function, it's not work. why...

Comment: it should work.. check the value of someValue.. if you still continue to face issues. you can try and upload the excel (or a simpler version of it) with your question and I'll take a closer look.

Comment: @AnanthaSharma Yes it works for macro. But doesn't work for function. I have updated my question above. Please help

Comment: Although this looks like a simple answer, it's a wrong answer to the above question.The original post creator asks if its possible for a user formula to write beyond the boundary of its own cell .The answer is A user defined formula cannot write values outside its own cell without significant effort.