# Assigning value to a cell in a function

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a code where one of the lines(   ***Range("H5").value = 10*** ) should assign a specific value to a specific cell. However it gives me an #VALUE! error on my cell. Here is my code please help!!:

```
Function TotalAdUnits(Money As Currency, CycleEarning As Integer) As Integer

 TapCost = 16
 TotalAdUnits = 0
 AdUnit = 0
 i = 1

 Money = Money + CycleEarning

 Do While (Money >= TapCost)

  Money = Money - TapCost
  TotalAdUnits = TotalAdUnits + Range("L1").Offset(i, 0)
  TapCost = Range("J2").Offset(i, 0)

  Range("H5").value = 10

  i = i + 1

 Loop

End Function
```

Comment: You cannot set a cells value from a UDF - a function used in this way can only return a value to the calling cell (or range, if it's used as an array function). Edit your function to return the value, instead of trying to set it directly.

Comment: @Tim, looks good to me, you should post as an answer...

Comment: @TimWilliams It can actually be done via a function if you are hell-bent on it. Complex but doable, http://stackoverflow.com/a/9493006/641067

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set a cells value from a UDF - a function used in this way can only return a value to the calling cell (or range, if it's used as an array function). Edit your function to return the value, instead of trying to set it directly.

Having said that, I'm not clear on exactly what you're trying to do with that function.  Why set the same value in a loop?

Also, if you reference ranges directly from your function, and those ranges are not passed as parameters, you need to include 
`Application.Volatile` 
in your function so Excel knows to recalculate it any time the sheet changes.

```
Function TotalAdUnits(Money As Currency, CycleEarning As Integer) As Integer

 TapCost = 16
 TotalAdUnits = 0
 AdUnit = 0
 i = 1

 Money = Money + CycleEarning

 Do While (Money >= TapCost)

     Money = Money - TapCost
     TotalAdUnits = TotalAdUnits + Range("L1").Offset(i, 0)
     TapCost = Range("J2").Offset(i, 0)

     Range("H5").value = 10

     i = i + 1

 Loop

 'need to return a value...
 TotalAdUnits = 10 '?
End Function
```

Comment: Actually, what I meant was for that line the following:     

     Range("H5").value = Range("J2").Offset(i, 0)