# VBA Output Write To Cell - #VALUE! Error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a UDF of mine work (in Excel 2003), and after debugging the problem appears to be summarized in this condensed version of my function:

```
Function btest(b_1 As Double) As Double    
    btest = 1    
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = b_1
    '^this is the bit I want to work but doesn't^
    End Function
```

This simulates my real function, which has a value assigned to it with no problems before the following cell output line which doesn't execute. I believe this is related to the `#VALUE!` error I get as a return, even though I used a `MsgBox` which showed that the function did have a numeric value.

Can anyone shed light on this please?

Also: what is the difference between

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1) = B
```

and

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = B
```

where
B is some numerical value?

Thanks

Comment: do you want to call your functions from VBA code or from Sheet cell?

Comment: additionally you could check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15659852/2143262), too

Comment: from another Sheet cell, e.g. A2

Comment: it looks like the problem is any UDF is not allowed to edit sheets, only return a single value...so if I want to edit another cell as part of the same process, I need to use a sub.

Comment: Is this correct, and if so, how would I go about that - sub within a function or function within a sub? I want my spreadsheet to automatically react to inputs as it would with a function - no buttons or special actions required.

Comment: yes, you can't manipulate cells from function if you call this function from excel cell... if you need to return value to more than one cell use `Sub`. If you than need to do it as a result of any action you can explore `events`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set a cell value from a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659779/set-a-cell-value-from-a-function)

Comment: Thanks very much everyone. A good answer is [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659779/set-a-cell-value-from-a-function) which has inspired me to call the function in a sheet-specific subroutine so it runs whenever Target is altered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you had already realised with

> it looks like the problem is any UDF is not allowed to edit sheets, only return a single value...so if I want to edit another cell as part of the same process, I need to use a sub"

a *standard* UDF can't change the sheet.

But in terms of your follow-up comment

> Is this correct, and if so, how would I go about that - sub within a function or function within a sub? I want my spreadsheet to automatically react to inputs as it would with a function - no buttons or special actions required.

You can use an Event

As an example:

- You want to track A1:A10 on a certain sheet for an input
- if this area is used you want to set `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value` to this value

**Question 1**

1. right click the tab of the sheet you want to track
2. View Code
3. Copy and Paste in the code below
   4  Press [alt](/questions/tagged/alt)[f11](/questions/tagged/f11) to return to Excel

**code**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Intersect(Target, Range("a1:10"))
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = rng1.Value
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**Question 2**

They are identical.

Answer (score 0):

You are right (in your comment) that a UDF cannot *change* a sheet, only return a value.

This holds true event if you call a `Sub` or `Function` from the UDF and try to have that change the sheet.  It will fail too.

Note: there is a (quite ugly) work around: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9493006/445425)