# VBA Excel Function to Set the Calling Cell .NumberFormat Property

Tags: excel, vba, number-formatting

I created this function and it works to put the value into the cell but it doesnt work to set the .NumberFormat property.

```
Public Function NewYears(year As Integer)
    'Determine the cell that called the function
    Dim rng As range
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("How-To").range(Application.Caller.Address)
    MsgBox rng.Address
    fxFormat = "[$" & holidayName & "]"
    NewYears = DateSerial(year, 1, 1)
    rng.NumberFormat = fxFormat  
End Function
```

Update For more information:

I will be having functions like =NewYears() that returns a date.

I will do this for any number of holidays.  I would like to format the field where it still stores the date but the .NumberFormat property has the name of the holiday

So =NewYears() would return "01/01/2014" but in the sheet it would appear as "New Years"

Comment: Kairan that's definitely not the info about sheet design/structure. Usually people do know how to call `UDF`... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Worksheet_Change` event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 39
    Target.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy" 
End Sub
```

Put this code in the `Sheets("How-To")` code module.  Modify to whatever color/etc that you want to format.

When you initially enter the function in the cell, it will trigger the change event  and this subroutine will execute.

Per Gary's comments (below), **recalculation of existing formula will not trigger this event**.

Comment: I don't believe the Work_Change will be triggered by a function calculation, you need a Calculate event macro to do that.

Comment: ahhh I think you're right. I only tested it by *entering* the function in the cell, which of course triggers the change.

Comment: In this case, entering the function will initially set the number format. Not sure if that would ever need to change based on OP, but very good comment from you @Gary'sStudent.

Answer (score 0):

Functions can only return values or manipulate Comments, they can't modify formats directly.

Comment: Can I say, call another Sub that takes a range and the Sub can manipulate it?  Of course I will give it a try

Comment: You can call a sub to format the cells, but not from within the UDF.

Comment: Use a sub to format the cells.  Run the sub directly rather than being called from within the function.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9493006/445425) for a rather ugly work around to this UDF limitation

Answer (score 0):

1. How many calculations are in your sheet/book?
2. Are the cells in a particular arranged column or everywhere or Random?

   If answer is Yes to first question I wouldn't suggest a volatile function triggers, well no one should. And things you do next depends on the answer to 2nd question.

Why dont you try "conditional formatting" though it could be a bit costly. Else if the Year cell should be in an organized column or cell make sure its format is ready-made to date.... if none of these apply, you may give us a better picture if your sheet's structure/design...

Comment: I added additional information to my original post - i think conditional would be difficult as my holiday dates may frequently change (for reasons I cant quickly explain)