# Writing Value to a Cell which is not calling the function, via VBA Function

Tags: vba, excel, function

I'm wondering if it is possible to write values to a cell in Excel via a VBA Function?

Aka neither line in the following function will call:

```
Function OffsetValue(myinput As Double) As Double
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value = myinput
    Call OffsetValueSub(myinput)
End Function

Sub OffsetValueSub(myinput As Double)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value = myinput
End Sub
```

But The following *Dummy* Sub will work correctly:

```
Sub Dummy()
    Call OffsetValueSub(100)
End Sub

Sub OffsetValueSub(myinput As Double)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value = myinput
End Sub
```

Is there something one has to do to be able to write to a cell which is not the cell which is calling the specific function?

Comment: Already covered here, search this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476282/cannot-vba-write-data-to-cells-in-excel-2007-2010-within-a-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be this workaround could do for you:

shorten down your `OffsetValue` function to:

```
Function OffsetValue(myinput As Double) As Double
    OffsetValue = myinput '<--| this will trigger worksheet 'Change' event
End Function
```

place the following sub in the code pane of the worksheet you want to use `Function OffsetValue()` in:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo ExitSub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Call OffsetValueSub(Target.Value) '<--| call 'OffsetValueSub()' and write input value where it has to
    Target.ClearContents '<--| should you ever want to erase any trace of the OffsetValue function
ExitSub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

if you don't want to remove the call to `OffsetValue()` from the cell you wrote it in  then just remove/comment `Target.ClearContents`

this is just a base code that you may want to enhance with:

- some checking of the `Target` range passed in to `Worksheet_Change()`

  you may want to check if it matches specific *Value* (e.g: checking `Target.Value` against some value range) or *Range* (e.g: checking `Target` range itself belonging to a predefined`Range`) criteria
- handle the same need throughout the whole workbook

  then you have to switch to `Sub ThisWorkbook_Change()` event handler use in ThisWorkbook code pane