# VBA: Creating cell comment within user defined function

Tags: excel, vba, comments, user-defined-functions

I have a UDF that makes a calculation based on a bunch of input variables. I am trying to make the UDF create a cell comment that contains information about those variables, but I am just getting the #VALUE! error.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
Function profit(income As Single, loss As Single) As Single
Dim cell As Range
cell = ActiveCell

profit = income - loss

call create_comment(cell, income, loss)

End function
```

Calling the sub:

```
Private Sub create_comment(cell As Range, income As Single, loss As Single)

cell.ClearComments
cell.Addcomment "income =" & income & "loss =" & loss

End Sub
```

All help appreciated!

Comment: Have a look at the [limitations](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel) of an UDF. And then you can have a look at _[It can be done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476282/cannot-vba-write-data-to-cells-in-excel-2007-2010-within-a-function)_. But if you do that then you are probably on your own :-)

Comment: Thanks, I have. I am unsure whether creating a cell comment counts a formatting. If it doesn't, it should be possible.

Comment: Comments are no formatting but you can also not add a shape with a UDF.

Comment: Note that I am trying to add the comment to the same cell as the function is in. I am not trying to change the value of another cell. Thanks

Comment: I have to correct my comment from above. You cann indeed add a shape with a UDF. I did not expect that.

Comment: Thanks! I suspect excel interpret the "call sub" as formatting or altering of other cells.

Comment: I posted an answer. I did not expect that you could add a shape resp. comment via an UDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your function like that

```
Function profit(income As Single, loss As Single, cell As Range) As Single
'Dim cell As Range
'cell = ActiveCell

profit = income - loss

Call create_comment(cell, income, loss)

End Function
```

And you enter the active cell in the call of the function like that

```
=profit(1000,10,H10)
```

Comment: Did this work out for you? I am now getting the #NAME? error

Comment: Yes, this worked for me. Maybe you just add the code to an empty sheet or press F9 to re-calculate. I work with Office/Excel 365.

Comment: Thanks!! You are a hero!!

Comment: Glad I could help. I also learned something ;-) Please mark the question as answered.