# Execute a user-defined function into another cell VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I need to automatize a process which execute various (a lot) user-defined function with different input parameters.

I am using the solution of timer API found in [I don't want my Excel Add-In to return an array (instead I need a UDF to change other cells)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520732/i-dont-want-my-excel-add-in-to-return-an-array-instead-i-need-a-udf-to-change/8711582#8711582) .

My question is the following: "Does anybody can explain to me HOW IT IS WORKING?" If I debug this code in order to understand and change what I need, I simply go crazy.

1) Let say that I am passing to the public function AddTwoNumbers 14 and 45. While inside AddTwoNumber, the Application.Caller and the Application.Caller.Address are chached into a collection (ok, easier than vectors in order not to bother with type). Application.Caller is kind of a structured object where I can find the function called as a string (in this case "my_function"), for example in Application.Caller.Formula.
!!! Nowhere in the collection mCalculatedCells I can find the result 59 stored.

2)Ok, fair enough. Now I pass through the two UDF routines, set the timers, kill the timers.
As soon as I am inside the AfterUDFRoutine2 sub, the mCalculatedCell(1) (the first -- and sole -- item of my collection) has MAGICALLY (??!?!?!!!??) obtained in its Text field exactly the result "59" and apparently the command Set Cell = mCalculatedCells(1) (where on the left I have a Range and on the right I have ... I don't know) is able to put this result "59" into the variable Cell that afterward I can write with the .Offset(0,1) Range property on the cell to the right.

I would like to understand this point because I would like to give MORE task to to inside a single collection or able to wait for the current task to be finished before asking for a new one (otherwise I am over-writing the 59 with the other result). Indeed I read somewhere that all the tasks scheduled with the API setTimer will wait for all the callback to be execute before execute itself (or something like this).

**As you can see I am at a loss. Any help would be really really welcomed.**

```
In the following I try to be more specific on what (as a whole) 
I am planning to achieved.
```

To be more specific, I have the function

```
public function my_function(input1 as string, Field2 as string) as double

/*some code */

end function
```

I have (let's say) 10 different strings to be given as Field2.

My strategy is as follow:

```
1)I defined (with a xlw wrapper from a C++ code) the grid of all my input values

2)define as string all the functions "my_function" with the various inputs

3)use the nested API timer as in the link to write my functions IN THE RIGHT CELLS as FORMULAS (not string anymore)

3)use a macro to build the entire worksheet and then retrieve the results.

4)use my xlw wrapper xll to process further my data.
```

You may wonder WHY should I pass through Excel instead of doing everything in C++. (Sometime I ask myself the same thing...) The prototype my_function that I gave above has inside some Excel Add-In that I need to use and they work only inside Excel.

It is working pretty well IN THE CASE I HAVE ONLY 1 "instance" of my_function to write for the give grid of input. I can even put inside the same worksheet more grids, then use the API trick to write various different my_functions for the different grids and then make a full calculation rebuild of the entire worksheet to obtain the result. It works.
However, as soon as I want to give more tasks inside the same API trick (because for the same grid of input I need more calls to my_function) I am not able to proceed any further.

```
After Axel Richter's comment I would like to ad some other information
```

@Axel Richter
Thank you very much for your reply.

Sorry for that, almost surely I wasn't clear with my purposes.

Here I try to sketch an example, I use integer for simplicity and let's say that my_function works pretty much as the SUM function of Excel (even if being an Excel native function I could call SUM directly into VBA but it is for the sake of an example).

If I have these inputs:
input1 = "14.5"
a vector of different values for Field2, for instance (11;0.52;45139)
and then I want to write somewhere my_function (which makes the sum of the two values given as input).

I have to write down in a cell =my_function(14.5;11), in the other =my_function(14.5;0.52) and in a third one =my_function(14.5;45139).

These input changes any time I need to refresh my data, then I cannot use directly a sub (I think) and, in any case, as far as I understand, in writing directly without the trick I linked, I will always obtain strings : something like '=my_function(14.5;0.52). Once evaluated (for example by a full rebuild or going over the written cell and make F2 + return) will give me only the string "=my_function(14.5;0.52)" and not its result.
I tried at the beginning to use an Evaluate method which works well as soon as I write something like 14.5+0.52, but it doesn't work as soon as a function (nor a user-defined function) is used instead.

This is "as far as I can understand". In the case you can enlighten me (and maybe show an easier track to follow), it would be simply GREAT.

Comment: `Application.Caller` returns a Range object in this case. Although Kevin's code is a good proof of concept, I personally would never use it in production.

Comment: Your Point 3 confuses me now ;-). The goal of the post, you have linked, is that a UDF can write into any cells and not only return an value for the cell it is called from. This is originally not possible. Your requirement:"write my functions IN THE RIGHT CELLS as FORMULAS" *is* possible without tricks.

Comment: @jogojapan
I agree with you that it is quite borderline and maybe to take only as a proof of principle, but I really don't have any idea to do it otherwise. Do you?

Comment: @Axel Richter
My answer is too long for a reply and I will edit directly to the main question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far the comments are correct in that they repeat the simple point that a User-Defined Function called a worksheet can only return a value, and all other actions that might inject values elsewhere into the worksheet calculation tree are forbidden.

That's not the end of the story. You'll notice that there are add-ins, like the Reuters Eikon market data service and Bloomberg for Excel, that provide functions which exist in a single cell **but which write blocks of data onto the sheet outside the calling cell**.

These functions use the RTD (Real Time Data) API, which is documented on MSDN:

[How to create a RTD server for Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/285339)

[How to set up and use the RTD function in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/289150)

You may find this link useful, too:

[Excel RTD Servers: Minimal C# Implementation](http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/Rtd3)

However, RTD is all about COM servers outside Excel.exe, you have to write them in another language (usually  C# or C++), and that isn't the question you asked: you want to do this in VBA.

But I have, at least, made a token effort to give the 'right' answer.

Now for the 'wrong' answer, and actually doing something Microsoft would rather you didn't do. You can't just call a function, call a subroutine or method from the function, and write to the secondary target using the subroutine: Excel will follow the chain and detect that you're injecting values into the sheet calculation, and the write will fail.

You have to insert a break into that chain; and this means using events, or a timer call, or (as in RTD) an external process.

I can suggest two methods that will actually work:

#### 1: Monitor the cell in the Worksheet_Change event:

`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 

Dim strFunc As String 
 
strFunc = "NukeThePrimaryTargets" 

If Left(Target.Formula, Len(strFunc) + 1) = strFunc Then 
    Call NukeTheSecondaryTargets 
End If 
 
End Sub`

Alternatively...

#### 2: Use the Timer callback API:

However, I'm not posting code for that: it's complex, clunky, and it takes a *lot* of testing (so I'd end up posting untested code on StackOverflow). But it does actually work.

I can give you an example of a tested Timer Callback in VBA:

[Using the VBA InputBox for passwords and hiding the user's keyboard input with asterisks.](http://excellerando.blogspot.co.uk/2015/01/asterisk-galling-using-inputbox-for.html)

But this is for an unrelated task. Feel free to adapt it if you wish.

Comment: Wow. Now it makes sense... better to change perspective and methods. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Edited with following requirements: It is necessary to run a user defined worksheet function, because there are addins called in this function and those work only within a Excel sheet. The function has to run multiple times with different parameters and its results have to be gotten from the sheet.

So this is my solution now:

```
Public Function my_function(input1 As Double, input2 As Double) As Double
 my_function = input1 + input2
End Function

Private Function getMy_Function_Results(input1 As Double, input2() As Double) As Variant
 Dim results() As Double

 'set the Formulas
 With Worksheets(1)
  For i = LBound(input2) To UBound(input2)
   strFormula = "=my_function(" & Str(input1) & ", " & Str(input2(i)) & ")"
   .Cells(1, i + 1).Formula = strFormula
  Next

 'get the Results
  .Calculate
  For i = LBound(input2) To UBound(input2)
   ReDim Preserve results(i)
   results(i) = .Cells(1, i + 1).Value
  Next
 End With
 getMy_Function_Results = results
End Function

Sub test()
 Dim dFieldInput2() As Double
 Dim dInput1 As Double

 dInput1 = Val(InputBox("Value for input1"))

 dInput = 0
 iIter = 0
 Do
  dInput = InputBox("Values for fieldInput2; 0=END")
  If Val(dInput) <> 0 Then
   ReDim Preserve dFieldInput2(iIter)
   dFieldInput2(iIter) = Val(dInput)
   iIter = iIter + 1
  End If
 Loop While dInput <> 0

 On Error GoTo noFieldInput2
 i = UBound(dFieldInput2)
 On Error GoTo 0

 vResults = getMy_Function_Results(dInput1, dFieldInput2)

 For i = LBound(vResults) To UBound(vResults)
  MsgBox vResults(i)
 Next

noFieldInput2:
End Sub
```

The user can input first a value input1 and then input multiple fieldInput2 until he inputs the value 0. Then the results will be calculated and presented.

Greetings

Axel

Comment: Thank you very much for this idea, but it works only in the case you are working with a sub. As far as I can see I need to put my values as inputs (and then use a function instead of a sub). This is because I cannot know in advance in which cells they are stored (and then inside a function go and read them). 
If a write a function which upload input1 and the vector fieldInput2, and subsequently call your subroutine, I am ejected out from the code at execution time at the line .Range("a1").Formula = strFormula1.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your requirements. Maybe some other ones do.

Comment: I believe this is due to the fact that a function cannot simply modify cell but only return a value (see for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501759/vba-update-other-cells-via-user-defined-function or http://www.vertex42.com/ExcelArticles/user-defined-functions.html).
I keep on digging ...
Cheers.

Comment: Just to be even clearer. If you change your code:

Dim fieldInput2(2) As Double
 fieldInput2(0) = 11
 fieldInput2(1) = 0.52
 fieldInput2(2) = 45139

 Dim input1 As Double
 input1 = 14.5

in a way such that you upload as input these values, I don't really see how you can write with .Range("a1").Values.

Your idea is brilliant but I cannot fix the format of my input. Bad luck...

Comment: Where should the values come from? User input? Read from file?