# Excel formula to Copy values from workbook to another using hyperlink

Tags: excel

I have a requirement to copy cell values from "**Sheet1**", cells **A1** and **A2** to "**Sheet2**" cells **B1** and **B2** respectively. I would like to set a hyperlink in Sheet1 and on clicking the link, Sheet2 should be open and values of A1 and A2 from Sheet1 should be copied to B1 and B2 in Sheet2.

Is there a way to do this using Excel formulae without using macros?

Comment: As @pnuts already pointed out: Excel formulas cannot change the value of another cell. There is only one workaround I have heard of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501759/vba-update-other-cells-via-user-defined-function Yet, it seems to me that this won't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

No. Excel formulae can't 'push' values.