# User defined Paste Special Function

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

```
Function PS(X As Range) As Double
    Range(X).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range(X).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Function
```

I am trying to create a function PS where it take value from cell and pastes special in the cell where the PS function is used. The above code not giving the desired value.

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to edit / change the content of cells with a worksheet function. That's not something you should be doing. [While some gifted users have found a way to circumvent this restriction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501759/vba-update-other-cells-via-user-defined-function) I strongly advise against it and rather ask you to share with us what you are really trying to achieve so that we can help you find a better solution.

Comment: I am trying to create a user defined function where it take value from cell and pastes special the value in the cell where the user defined function is used.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need is a function which gets the value of the range you selected. Place this in a **new module**:

```
Function Hardcode(r As Range)
    Hardcode = r.Value
End Function
```

For example: placing `=Hardcode(A1)` into cell `B1` returns the value of cell `A1`. However, from my understanding, you also want to hardcode the new value of `B1`. To do this you need a separate `Sub`

Place this code in the **worksheet module** corresponding to the worksheet you wish to use the above function on:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If InStr(LCase(Target.Formula), "hardcode") Then
        Target.Value = Target.Value
    End If
End Sub
```