# Excel VBA - Assign cell properties throws error number 1004

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

Folks, I am struggling to get this piece of code to run as Macro from an excel sheet (named "Kalender"):

```
Public Function dcTest(s As String) As String
  Dim ws As Worksheet

  On Error GoTo dcTestExit
  Err.Clear

  Set ws = ActiveSheet
  ' Set ws = Worksheets("Kalender") '... same error (and yes, the sheet exists!)
  ' ws.Cells(2, 2).FormulaR1C1 = s
  ws.Cells(2, 2).Value = s

dcTestExit:
  Set E = Err

End Function
```

The error occurs once I try to write to the `Value` or `FormulaR1C2` property. The Function is called as a "user defined" function from an excel sheet like `=dcTest("whatever")`.

Can you point me into the right direction? RT(F)M welcome as long as with details...

Cheers,
  ChrisF

Comment: Use a **sub** and not a **function**.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how/where the function is being called..? I've tried numerous variations of your code from the debug window, and also an ActiveX button, and I can't get it to fail.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent advice is correct! Obviously one can not change cell contents from within a function, but only from within a sub.

Answer (score 1):

A UDF isn't allowed to directly change values at arbitrary locations. See [VBA - Update Other Cells via User-Defined Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501759/vba-update-other-cells-via-user-defined-function) for a workaround.