# Method/Process to Handle Data in Persistent Manner

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, data-manipulation

I've been banging my head against this for about a year on and off and I just hit a crunch time.

Business Issue:  We use a software called Compeat Advantage (General Ledger system) and they provide a Excel add-in that allows you to use a function to retrieve data from the Microsoft SQL database.  The problem is that it must make a call to the database for each cell with that function.  On average it takes about .2 seconds to make the call and retrieve the data.  Not bad except when a report has these in volume.  Our standard report built with it has ~1,000 calls.  So by math it takes just over 3 minutes to produce the report.

Again, in and of itself not a bad amount of time for a fully custom report.  The issue I am trying to address that is one of the smaller reports ran, AND in some cases we have to produce 30 variants of the same report unique per location.

Arguments in function are; Unit(s) [String], Account(s) [String], Start Date, End Date.  All of this is retrieved in a SUM() for all info to result in a single [Double] being returned.

```
SELECT SUM(acctvalue)
FROM acctingtbl
WHERE DATE BETWEEN startDate AND endDate AND storeCode = Unit(s) AND Acct = Account(s)
```

Solution Sought:  For the standard report there is only three variation of the data retrieved (Current Year, Prior Year, and Budget) and if they are all retrieved in bulk but in detailed tables/arrays the 3 minute report would drop to less than a second to produce.

I want to find a way to retrieve in line item detail and store locally to access without the need to create a ODBC for every single function call on the sheet.

```
SELECT Unit, Account, SUM(acctvalue)
FROM acctingtbl
WHERE date BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
GROUP BY Unit, Account
```

Help: I am failing to find a functional way to do this.  The largest problem I have is the scope/persistence of data.  It is easy to call for all the data I need from the database, but keeping it around for use is killing me.  Since these are spreadsheet functions after the call the data in the variables is released so I end up in the same spot.  Each function call on the sheet takes .2 seconds.

I have tried storing the data in a CSV file but continue to have data handling issues is so far as moving it from the CSV to an array to search and sum data.  I don't want to manipulate registry to store the info.

I am coming to the conclusion if I want this to work I will need to call the database, store the data in a .veryhidden tab, and then pull it forward from there.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated on what process I should use.

Comment: I'm a little confused but can't you use either powerquery or SSIS to do this?

Comment: It's really hard to type out.  Never tried pwerquery - looking into it now.

Answer (score 0):

Okay!

After some lucking Google-fu I found a passable work around.

[VBA - Update Other Cells via User-Defined Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501759/vba-update-other-cells-via-user-defined-function)  This provided many of the answers.

Beyond his code I had to add code to make that sheet calculate ever time the UDF was called to check the trigger.  I did that by doing a simple cell +  cell formula and having a random number placed in it every time the workbook calculates.

I am expanding the code in the Workbook section now to fill in the holes.

Should solve the issue!