# #VALUE! error returned by user written time-weighted average function

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a function in VBA that computes a time-weighted average, but the `#VALUE!` error appears when I try to use the function in my worksheet.

While trying to debug I have been able to validate my approach to change `CurRPM` by iterating `CurOffset` and using `CurRng = rng.Offset(CurOffset, 0)`. The effect of changing `CurRng` is to iterate down the RPM column, checking if the cell under `CurRng` is either empty, the same as `CurRPM`, or non-empty and different from `CurRPM`.

```
Public Function TIMEAVERAGE(rng As Range) As Long

'Initializing Variables
Dim CurTime As Integer
Dim CurRPM As Integer
Dim CurSum As Integer
Dim CurOffset As Integer
CurOffset = 0
CurSum = 0

'The input cell is the first RPM
'The cell to the left of the input cell is the second RPM
CurTime = rng.Offset(0, -1)
CurRPM = rng

'Keep calculating as long as the cell below CurRng isn't empty
While IsEmpty(CurRng.Offset(1, 0)) = False
    'If the cell below has the same RPM, look at next cell
    If CurRng.Offset(1, 0) = CurRPM Then
        CurOffset = CurOffset + 1
        CurRng = rng.Offset(CurOffset, 0)
    Else:
        'Otherwise, add the previous RPM's contribution to the average
        'CurTime, as shown, is the start of the previous RPM
        CurSum = CurSum + CurRPM * (CurRng.Offset(0, -1) - CurTime)
        'Change CurRPM and CurTime for the new RPM
        CurRPM = CurRng.Offset(1, 0)
        CurTime = CurRng.Offset(0, -1)
        CurOffset = CurOffset + 1
        CurRng = rng.Offset(CurOffset, 0)
    End If

Wend

'Add the contributions of the final RPM
CurSum = CurSum + CurRPM * (CurRng.Offset(0, -1) - CurTime)

'Return the final TIMEAVERAGE
TIMEAVERAGE = CurSum / CurRng.Offset(0, -1)

End Function
```

The desired result from this program is returning 150 if the user enters `=TIMEAVERAGE(B2)` for the cells below. Instead, a `#VALUE!` error is returned.

```
       A       B        
 ________________    
1|    Time | RPM
2|    0    | 100
3|    1    | 100
4|    2    | 100
5|    3    | 200
6|    4    | 200
7|    5    | 200
8|    6    | 200
```

Comment: A user defined function (UDF) always returns `#VALUE!` if there is an unhandled error in the function. To debug it make an additional procedure that calls `Debug.Print TIMEAVERAGE(Worksheets("MySheet").Range("B2"))` then go through the code step by step using F8 to see where you get any errors. Tell us which errors you get and where.

Comment: `CurRng` is neither declared nor initialized

Comment: Please note that if `CurRng` is meant to be a `Range` object. Then `CurRng = rng.Offset(CurOffset, 0)` won't work because a UDF is **not** allowed to change other cell's values. • I recommend to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)* to force proper variable declaration.

Comment: @PEH: Probably the OP meant to `Set` the variable

Comment: `..a UDF is not allowed to change other cell's values...` @Pᴇʜ That is not true ;)

Comment: I believe you are using the formula as `=TIMEAVERAGE(A2)` in Cell B2. But with `CurTime = rng.Offset(0, -1)`, your formula will give an error for Cell B2 as you are trying to access a column which is on the left of Col A which doesn't exist.

Comment: @SiddharthRout But not without any fancy tricks. I only see the trick doing it [indirectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501759/vba-update-other-cells-via-user-defined-function). But any direct cell value change like `Cells(1, 1) = "AAAA"` will cause `#VALUE!`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: No Fancy Tricks.. :D A simple `.Evaluate`... You may want to see [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433096/using-a-udf-in-excel-to-update-the-worksheet)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Well not that *fancy* but still tricked and no direct change of a cell value. To do this you first have to learn/understand that any *direct* value change will not work.

Comment: I saw the observation made by @FunThomas and added `Dim CurRng As Range` after initializing `CurOffset` as well as `CurRng = rng` immediately before the while loop. during the debugging suggestsed by @PEH, I received this dialogue box: run-time error '91': Object variable r With block variable not set, with the `CurRng = rng` line highlighted. This error is also producted if this highlighted line is replaced with CurRng = rng.Offset(CurOffset, 0). Is this related to the second comments by @FunThomas and @PEH?

Comment: To clarify, this is the subroutine I have used for debugging:Sub `TimeAverageDebug()`

    `Debug.Print TIMEAVERAGE(Worksheets("Testbed").Range("B2"))`

`End Sub`

Comment: If `CurRng` is a `Range` it means it is an *object* and for objects you have to use `Set` like `Set CurRng = rng`.

Comment: I was able to fix the problem, by using @FunThomas and @PEH's advice to use `Set`. I replaced the `CurRng = rng.Offset(CurOffset, 0)` lines with `Set CurRng = rng.Offset(CurOffset, 0)`.