# Does VBA allows to assign a value to a cell from inside a function code?

Tags: excel, vba, function

I have a VBA user defined function. Besides to assigning a value to the function, I need to assign a value to a cell which is not the cell calling the function.
However, when I try to execute the code, it fails: the error #VALUE appears in the cell from which the function is called and in the other cell no value is assigned.
Is it a VBA excel limitation or is there a bug in my code?
Here is the code sample:

```
Function zz()
    zz = "OK"
    Row = ActiveCell.Row
    col = ActiveCell.Column
    Cells(Row + 1, col) = "pippi"
End Function
```

Many thanks.

Comment: UDF's (used in formulas in the worksheet) are not able to modify cell values directly. The following post has some responses giving work-arounds that might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/q/12501759/212869

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to directly update another cell, your UDF can return an array, which can "auto-spill" into an adjacent cell (depending on how you orient your array)

https://www.contextures.com/excelspillformulaexamples.html

For example:

```vb
Function zz()
    Dim rv(1 To 2, 1 To 1)
    rv(1, 1) = "OK"
    rv(2, 1) = "pippi"
    zz = rv
End Function
```

Note: inside a UDF you can use either `Application.Caller` or `Application.ThisCell` to refer to the cell containing the formula.  If you use `ActiveCell` there's no guarantee that's going to be the cell you want.

Comment: That is a clever workaround, Many thanks!
Anyway I got that vba does not allow to assign a value to a cell from a function directly.