# Copy a Range using a function and report errors

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my code

```
Function copyToNewRange(a As Range, b As Range)
' a is input, b is output
    If a.Cells.Count <> b.Cells.Count Then
        copyToNewRange = "ERROR"
        Exit Function
    End If
    For i = 1 To a.Cells.Count
        b.Cells(i, 1) = a.Cells(i, 1)
    Next i
    copyToNewRange = "COPIED"
End Function
```

I would use it thus:

`=copyToNewRange(A11:A30,C11:C30)`

in a cell not in the input or output range!
Why do I get #VALUE!?
I note that commenting out `b.Cells(i, 1) = a.Cells(i, 1)` allows it to run, but what is the error in this line?

Comment: I don't think this is possible as is. A Function routine is used to return values and not execute object properties and method. But somehow, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433096/using-a-udf-in-excel-to-update-the-worksheet) shows a way to alter properties of cells. I'm not sure if it can be used the way you want though but I think it is a start.

Answer (score 2):

A UDF (a user defined function, called from a worksheet) cannot *directly* modify other cells, it can only return a value.  There are, however, workarounds.

One such workaround is to construct a call to a `Sub` as a string, and use `Evaluate` to execute it.

Something like this:

```
Function copyToNewRange(rSrc As Range, rDst As Range)
    Dim sSub As String
    If rSrc.Columns.Count > 1 Or rDst.Columns.Count > 1 Then
        copyToNewRange = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    ElseIf rSrc.Rows.Count <> rDst.Rows.Count Then
        copyToNewRange = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    Else
        sSub = "copyToNewRangeSub(" & _
               rSrc.Address(True, True, xlA1, True) & "," & _
               rDst.Address(True, True, xlA1, True) & ")"
        rSrc.Worksheet.Evaluate sSub
        copyToNewRange = vbNullString
    End If
End Function


Sub copyToNewRangeSub(rSrc As Range, rDst As Range)
    rDst.Value = rSrc.Value
End Sub
```

Note, there are several other issues in your code I have addressed

1. When you want your function to return an err, return an ... Error
2. To ensure the ranges are shaped correctly, counting cells alone is not enough
3. Don't loop over a range, copy it in one go.
4. Your function should return *something*
5. You should `Dim` all your variables (use Option Explicit to force this)
6. Use meaningfull parameter names

Thanks to [Tim Willaims for the concept](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23437280/445425)

Comment: Many thanks for illuminating response. Have to say I don't see why VBA function should be so anal. BTW reason for not doing copy in one go is that I want to do some other things on the way, just got tripped up at first stage!

Comment: Glad to help.  Re copy in one go, just be aware that looping a range is slow.  If you find performance to be a problem, consider using a Variant Array approach ( there are lots of examples on SO)

Answer (score 0):

In a worksheet, you *can't* use a function that DOES things. Only one that returns data. That is quite logical, since the function is evaluated every time the sheet changes.
If you really want that behaviour, use the `Worksheet_Change` event.
Also note that, in your example, it is very uneffective to copy cells 1 by 1, compared to copy a range at once.

Comment: Many thanks for helpful response. See other comments. Will look at Worksheet_Change event (but surely purpose of any function is actually to *do* something!)