# How to write a formula in a cell with a function?

Tags: function, excel, vba

I would like write a formula in a specific cells with a function.

I have written this, but it doesn't work and I don't understand why :

```
Function formulaCell(x, y)

ActiveSheet.Cells(x, y).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C=0,"""",R[-1]C)"

End Function
```

Excel return #VALEUR

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wait. Are you writing a formula into a cell so that it changes formulas in other cells?

Comment: This is a case of *"you can't get there from here"*. Functions are intended (and restricted) to return a value into the cell that they originate in. They cannot change the values or formulas in other cells. TBH, I remember seeing someone overcome this to change another cell's color by calling a public sub macro from within the function but never to insert a formula into a cell.

Comment: @Jeeped: Is this what you're thinking of? [Using a UDF in Excel to update the worksheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433096/using-a-udf-in-excel-to-update-the-worksheet)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett - Although I believe the one I saw was in the TechNet Excel mailing list, that one looks pretty close and it seems like the same time frame.

Comment: @Crapsy you need to read some VB documentation: Functions need to make an **asingnment** so the code needs: `formulaCell = "Something"` that xplains the #VALEUR

Comment: Although it didn't work

Comment: @Taosique Yes, it's what I'm doing. I choose to do this because I want that the function recalculate when there are something change in the  sheet.

Comment: @Jeeped : Do you think I can applicate this for my function ?

Comment: @OlegarioFuentes Yes, it's true but even with this didn't work !

Comment: From your expanded description in these comments, it sounds like an `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(...))` might work. Why not try editing your question to describe what you are actually trying to accomplish and we can see if an alternate solution is applicable? A dynamic named range might be another possibility.

Comment: It may be easier to just have the formula [recalculate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195517.aspx) on a [`Worksheet_Change`-event?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx). Most functions should recalculate automatically if relevant changes are made anyway, I believe?

Comment: @Jeeped I'm interested by your idee, but I don't understand how apply this in my function ?

Answer (score 1):

Your function will work just fine **if the function is not called from a cell.**
For example, here it is call from a **Sub:**

```
Sub MAIN()
    Dim msg As String
    msg = formulaCell(3, 3)
    MsgBox msg
End Sub

Function formulaCell(x As Long, y As Long) As String
    ActiveSheet.Cells(x, y).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C=0,"""",R[-1]C)"
    formulaCell = "Mission Accomplished!!"
End Function
```

A *UDF()* in a **cell** can only return a value to that cell.  A *UDF()* in a **Sub** can do much more!