# 2D array values to sheet at specific location

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, range

I'm trying to get the values of a 2D array onto a worksheet, starting at a certain cell.
For example, in cell `A1`, I type the formula `=testArray2Sheet(D7)`
The expected outcome would be that the values appear on the sheet, the first value being in cell `D7` and spanning 18 rows down and 3 columns across.

My current code just stops executing at this line: `targetRange.Value = arr` and exits without throwing a warning or an error.
Cell `A1` just says `#VALUE`.
I have no idea why though...

```
Function testArray2Sheet(firstCell As range)
    Dim ret As Boolean 'dummy return value
    Dim targetRange As range
    Dim lastCell As range
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim rows, cols As Integer
    Dim i, j As Integer

    'Determine size of array
    rows = 18
    cols = 3

    'Make sure the array has the new dimensions
    ReDim arr(1 To rows, 1 To cols)

    'Fill the array with values
    For i = 1 To 18
    For j = 1 To 3
        arr(i, j) = i * j
    Next
    Next

    'firstCell is the top-left corner of the targetRange
    'Now determine the bottom-right corner of the targetRange
    Set lastCell = firstCell.Offset(rows, cols)

    'Create the targetRange
    Set targetRange = range(firstCell, lastCell)

    'Put the values of the array to the targetRange
    'This should me the values appear in the worksheet
    targetRange.Value = arr

    'Return a dummy value, because a function needs to return something
    testArray2Sheet = ret
End Function
```

Comment: You are trying to write to a sheet in a function? With the exception of [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433096/using-a-udf-in-excel-to-update-the-worksheet), you can not write to a different cell using a function

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/170787

Comment: @TimWilliams: You have a long life! I was just thinking of you when I linked one of your posts in my above comment

Comment: Have you considered using a `Sub` instead of a `Function`?

Comment: Just to note it, your current code will work fine as long as you call it from a `Sub` and not as a UDF.  `Sub test(): testArray2Sheet [a1]: End Sub` would work.  If you do that, you will also find that your output array is 1 row and column too large.  Need to do `.Offset(rows-1, cols-1)`.  `Offset` is how many rows to move.  Alternatively, you could do `firstCell.Resize(rows, cols).Value = arr` and skip the `lastCell` and `targetRange` business.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To move an array into the sheet, place the array formula (UDF) in the cells you want to receive the values.  Say the UDF is:

```
Function testArray2Sheet()
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim rows As Long, cols As Long
    Dim i As Long, J as Long

    rows = 18
    cols = 3

    'Make sure the array has the new dimensions
    ReDim arr(1 To rows, 1 To cols)


    For i = 1 To 18
      For j = 1 To 3
          arr(i, j) = i * j
      Next
    Next

    testArray2Sheet = arr
End Function
```

First hi-light a block of cells, say cells **B5** through **D22**.
Then click in the Formula Bar and enter the array formula:

```
=testArray2Sheet()
```

(using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key)

and you should see:

[image]

It is the block of cells in which the formula is entered that determines the destination of the array.