# Getting an Excel UDF to Return a Hyperlink

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

Currently to get a *UDF* to return a hyperlink I use something like:

```
Public Function HyperActive() As String
    HyperActive = "http://www.cnn.com"
End Function
```

and in a worksheet cell, I use:

```
=HYPERLINK(hyperactive(),"news")
```

to make a nice, "click-able" link.

I would like to have the UDF return a "click-able" link directly.  I have tried:

```
Public Function HyperActive() As Hyperlink
    Dim h As Hyperlink
    h.Address = "http://www.cnn.com"
    Set HyperActive = h
End Function
```

just returns **#VALUE!** in the cell!  How can get this to work??

Comment: I think your out of luck; A UDF cannot modify the state of a cell/sheet, just its  value. (You cant even change colours)

Comment: You'd have to use Windows timers I think. What's wrong with the `HYPERLINK` function?

Comment: I agree with @AlexK - I don't think this is possible, or at least it hasn't been for quite a while. I even tried having the function call a sub to do it, no luck.

Comment: Have you tried this trick yet? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433096/using-a-udf-in-excel-to-update-the-worksheet

Comment: @ByronWall  Thanks.....I tried it....I discovered that a *UDF* **can** return a Hyperlink Object to a sub, but not to a worksheet cell....so I am using a sub to insert the hyperlink to a cell.

Comment: Post your code when you finish.  I'm curious.

Comment: @ByronWall  I will later to day....once I do some clean-up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyperlinks like to be added to worksheets. You can add them to ranges two if you like. This function will add just that site, you can always flesh it out to take more args of you like.

It adds the hyperlink to the current selected cell. Though you could just as well change it to what ever you liked.

```
Public Function HyperActive(ByRef rng As Range)
With ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
.Add Anchor:=rng, _
     Address:="http://www.cnn.com", _
     ScreenTip:="Click to go to the Cnn Website", _
     TextToDisplay:="CNN Website"
End With
End Function

Sub Calling_The_Hyper_link()
Call HyperActive(Selection)
End Sub
```

If you add Public Function `HyperActive(byref sh as worksheet, ByRef rng As Range)` you could control which sheet it goes in too.