# The name that you entered is not valid" error

Tags: vba, excel

I define my own simple Sub

```
Sub test1()
    MsgBox "Hello"
End Sub
```

but when I try to reference it in a cell

```
=test1()
```

I get the following error prompter:

```
**The name that you entered is not valid
Reason for this:
1) The name does not begin with a letter or underscore
2) The name contains a space or other invalid character
3) The name conflicts with a Excel built in name or name of another object in the workbook**
```

I have no named ranges and the macro is runs without problems in the Macro manager window.

**What does this error message mean?

Do I need to name macro in a certain way to be able to use it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

- First, your Sub must be a Function.
- Second, you need to place the code in a Module, not behind any Sheet or ThisWorkbook.

Comment: just to add to this, it still wouldn't work as a function due to UDF limitations. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/170787#mt1

Comment: Correct. The message box does appear after typing `=test1()` in a cell but of course returns zero. I believe the OP just wanted to test.

Comment: Of course, rules are always made to be broken... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433096/using-a-udf-in-excel-to-update-the-worksheet/31720319

Comment: The macro is in a module. Does it need to have a special name?
The problem with converting it into a function is that apparently functions cannot change any attributes like background color the calling cell. II tried this.

Comment: To run a macro (Sub), you cannot use the method you posted.  You must use the Macro Dialog box, or you could place a button on the worksheet.