# Problems defining a cell value from within VBA

Tags: vba, excel

My code checks the values for cells F8 and H8, and if they're the same it should set CELL A1 to "dim".

```
Function plchk()

Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("check")

     If CDbl(Trim(sheet.Range("F8").Value)) = CDbl(Trim(sheet.Range("H8").Value)) Then


       sheet.Range("A1").Value = "dim"


    End If



End Function
```

On executing this code ,I keep getting the error "VALUE"

Comment: Why `Function` and not `Sub`? Where are you calling this from?

Comment: This part of the code isn't the full scope. It's a function as I will be passing variables into it once I've got the structure ready, and I will be expecting it to return a value as output as well as manipulating specific cells on the sheet.

Comment: ok but you are not calling this function from the sheet I hope?

Comment: Why what's the problem with calling it from the same sheet?

Comment: You cannot update other cells barring a few exceptions such as [These](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433096/using-a-udf-in-excel-to-update-the-worksheet). You may want to see [This](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/170787)

Comment: Thanks man, I didn't know about this.

Comment: I'd re-think the structure: Use a sub that takes arguments, and have public variables that hold the return values from the sub. Then you can still manipulate the workbook environment.