# #Value error while accessing user defined function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Code works fine when I access function from VBA however when I call the same function in excel cell (`postalcode("23.0776120,72.6538530")`, I get #Value error. My code is:

```
Function PostalCode(latlng As String) As String

Dim xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim xEmpDetails As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim xParent As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim xChild As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim Col, Row As Integer

Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
xmlDoc.async = False
xmlDoc.validateOnParse = False
' use XML string to create a DOM, on error show error message
If Not xmlDoc.Load("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=" & latlng) Then
    Err.Raise xmlDoc.parseError.ErrorCode, , xmlDoc.parseError.reason
End If

Set xEmpDetails = xmlDoc.DocumentElement
Set xParent = xEmpDetails.FirstChild

Row = 1
Col = 1

Dim xmlNodeList As IXMLDOMNodeList

Set xmlNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//formatted_address")

 Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 6).Value = xmlNodeList.Item(0).Text
 Dim xyz As String
 PostalCode = xmlNodeList.Item(0).Text
' PostalCode = "Not Found (try again, you may have done too many too fast)"
MsgBox PostalCode

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It's a documented limitation of User-Defined Functions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/170787) that you **cannot** generally operate on or manipulate range/worksheet objects within a UDF called from the worksheet. While you can do most value/property queries, you can't change the environment:

> A user-defined function called by a formula in a worksheet cell cannot
>   change the environment of Microsoft Excel. This means that such a
>   function cannot do any of the following:
>
> - Insert, delete, or format cells on the spreadsheet.
> - Change another cell's value.
> - Move, rename, delete, or add sheets to a workbook.
> - Change any of the environment options, such as calculation mode or screen views.
> - Add names to a workbook. Set properties or execute most methods.

I suspect that stepping through this code using F8 key in the VBE will identify the error, probably `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,6).Value`.

The basic rationale behind this limitation is to prevent infinite loops/circular references.

[There are ways to circumvent this limitation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433096/using-a-udf-in-excel-to-update-the-worksheet)

Comment: Thanks a ton!! After commenting "Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,6).Value"..I got the result..