# VBA #VALUE!" error while using a Function

Tags: excel, vba, function

Still one hair remaining... not for long

This :

```
Function Around(Compare As String)

Around = (Range(Compare).Value = Range(Compare).Offset(-1, 0).Value) Or (Range(Compare).Value = Range(Compare).Offset(1, 0).Value)

End Function
```

generates a #VALUE! in the cell that calls it

I cannot figure out why

Any clues ?

I think [#Value error while accessing user defined function in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38306826/value-error-while-accessing-user-defined-function-in-vba) does not apply here.

Comment: This won't work if the `Range(Compare)` evaluates to something in row 1. The offset of -1 tries to access row 0, which doesn't exist. That's the only way I can get a #VALUE error out of this (although I'm only working with one worksheet - the unqualified `Range`'s are also potentially problematic).

Comment: Good point. The error appears within the sheet, even far from top cell - and this is within a single sheet, I've done it in a minimalist way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're typing the formula in like `=Around(E8)`, when you need to type it in as `=Around("E8")` since `Compare` is a `String`:

[image: img1]

If you want to type it without quotation marks, then you need to declare `Compare` as a `Range` and change some syntax:

```
Function Around(Compare As Range)

    Around = (Compare.Value = Compare.Offset(-1, 0).Value) Or (Compare.Value = Compare.Offset(1, 0).Value)

End Function
```

[image: img2]

Comment: Of course... feel silly not to have though about it, it is obvious when reading the code. Thanks a lot !

Comment: And btw, to get it working like a standard Excel function, I've also added the volatile instruction =Function Around(Compare As Range)

    Application.Volatile
    Around = (Compare.Value = Compare.Offset(-1, 0).Value) Or (Compare.Value = Compare.Offset(1, 0).Value)

End Function