# Custom excel formula function UDF to count Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel, vba, function, udf

Has anyone run across a function that will actually work with conditional formatting?

there are some addons for kutools and albebits but they are not formula based (you have to select everything manually)

I have found this, but only works with manual formatting

```
Function ColorFunction(rColor As Range, rRange As Range, Optional SUM As Boolean)
Dim rCell As Range
Dim lCol As Long
Dim vResult
lCol = rColor.Interior.ColorIndex
If SUM = True Then
   For Each rCell In rRange
    If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol Then
            vResult = WorksheetFunction.SUM(rCell) + vResult
    End If
   Next rCell
Else
    For Each rCell In rRange
    If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol Then
            vResult = 1 + vResult
    End If
   Next rCell
End If
ColorFunction = vResult
End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following on from @Jeeped and @Comintern...

This works for me - a simplified example:

```
Function WrapCountReds(rRange)
    WrapCountReds = rRange.Parent.Evaluate("CountReds(" & _
                          rRange.Address(False, False) & ")")
End Function

'can't call this directly from a worksheet but can be called via evaluate
Public Function CountReds(rRange As Range)

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim vResult

    For Each rCell In rRange
      If rCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
             vResult = 1 + vResult
      End If
    Next rCell

    CountReds = vResult
End Function
```

Worksheet usage example:

```
=WrapCountReds("A1:A100")
```

Comment: Interesting. I never would have thought to use Evaluate as a wrapper function.

Comment: @Comintern - related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433096/using-a-udf-in-excel-to-update-the-worksheet/23437280#23437280