# VBA function not hidding columns when used in an excel cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use the functions below to hide columns

```
Function SCPArgsShowOnly() As Boolean
    Dim sColsToHide As String
    sColsToHide = "E:I,M:N"
    hideCols sColsToHide
    SCPArgsShowOnly = True
End Function

'======================================================
Sub hideCols(sCols As String)
    Dim sTemp() As String, allCols As String
    sTemp = Split(sCols, ",")
    allCols = "A:N"

    With Sheets("Functions")
        .Columns(allCols).Hidden = False

        For i = LBound(sTemp) To UBound(sTemp)
            .Columns(sTemp(i)).Hidden = True
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

It works fine when I run it through the debugger window. But it only returns true when I use it in a cell like this `= SCPArgsShowOnly()`

What am I missing?

Comment: you can't use a UDF to hide columns

Comment: how do you call it if not from debugger window? do you have an autostart macro for your excel file?

Comment: How do you call `SCPArgsShowOnly()` ? It does return true every time.

Comment: Shai is right it can't be done with a UDF embedded in the worksheet - but maybe when it's enabled by a button?

Comment: As Shai says a standard UDF can't interact with the sheet.  But here's a [workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23437280/445425)

Answer (score 2):

Excel does not allow calling functions that DO something from a cell.
Only functions that just return a value can be used, and that seems quite logical.
Imagine your columns appearing or disappearing whenever an entry in the sheet triggers a recalc ?