# Insert a value to a cell in excel using formula in another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to insert a value to a cell in excel using formula in another cell.

Say

```
A1 = "Test"
B1 = formula to insert A1 to C1
C1 = A1
```

Can I write a formula in `B1` to insert value in `C1`?
I don't need any formulas in `C1`.
If Yes, What should be the formula?

Comment: you can achieve this with VBA but I am not sure about the same with just formaulas

Comment: I don't understand the question. `A1` is `'test'` and `C1` is `=A1`, but `B1`? And what do you want with the formula of `B1`? Please provide a sample input and desired output.

Comment: You cannot change the value of another cell using a native worksheet function or formula and [you are not supposed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433096/using-a-udf-in-excel-to-update-the-worksheet) to be able to do this in VBA either. The reasoning is valid; cyclic calculation that produces circular references that are too complex to be reasonably determined.

Comment: Is B1 supposed to be just a logical test returning TRUE or FALSE whether to make C1 = A1? In that case, it seems like a simple IF statement in C would work. =IF(B1=TRUE,A1,"")

Answer (score 1):

If there it is next to the cell AND has no value in B2, it is possible, otherwise it is not.

Use Split()

```
Split(CONCATENATE("Text for B1#Sperator$$",A1),"#Sperator$$",FALSE)
```

It really depends.

EDIT
Out dated. Only works in google sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Without using VBA or formulas in column C you can't achieve this.

A simple solution using formulas:

In cell `C1`, paste the following formula and drag it down:

```
=IF(B1=1;A1;"")
```

[image]

So `if` the content of cell `B1 is equal to 1`, your cell at `column C` will display the respective value of the `same row` at `column A`.