# Using Application.Caller inside personal Function

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use Application.Caller inside a Function (code below), but Excel returns a #VALUE and the background color is not set.

The personal function is called from an Excel cell. The idea is to map RGB values to color display in a "synchronous" fashion (i.e. without having to press a button).

When I run the following function through the debugger and step just before the instruction `vCaller.Interior.Color = RGB(rlev, glev, blev)`, I can manually set the background color to green by pasting the exact same instruction in the execution console. So I'm puzzled as to why Excel is failing but VBA isn't.

Any clue ?

```
Public Function RGB_print(rlev As Integer, glev As Integer, blev As Integer) 
As String

Dim vCaller As Variant

Set vCaller = Application.Caller
If TypeName(vCaller) = "Range" Then
    vCaller.Interior.Color = RGB(rlev, glev, blev)
End If
RGB_print = ""

End Function
```

Comment: A function called from a cell cannot change that cell's colour (or any other cell's)

Comment: Where & how are you calling this code?

Comment: I am trying to map RGB values to color display in a "synchronous" way (i.e. without having to press a button). So maybe I can change another cell's color if it sounds less dangerous

Comment: @Absinthe : I'm calling the function from an Excel cell

Comment: @Rory : can I execute anything that read like "someCell.Interior.Color = RGB(...)" ? It seems that I can't

Comment: No you can't do that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433096/using-a-udf-in-excel-to-update-the-worksheet/23437280#23437280  but it's worth pointing out that using code like this may well have unforseen side-effects

Comment: @TimWilliams : wow thanks this is the answer I was looking for. If you want to post this as an answer I'll mark it. Or maybe I should juste delete my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I completely agree with the comment from @Rory - I'd never use this code in my own projects, but I wanted to see anyway....

If in a normal module you create this function:

```
Public Function RGB_print(rlev As Integer, glev As Integer, blev As Integer)
    Application.Volatile
End Function
```

Then in your sheet add this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim rFormula As Range
    Dim vForm As Variant
    Dim sArguments As String
    Dim sFormula As String
    Dim rgblev As Variant

    Set rFormula = Sheet1.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    For Each vForm In rFormula
        If InStr(vForm.FormulaLocal, "RGB_print") <> 0 Then
            sFormula = vForm.FormulaLocal
            sArguments = Mid(sFormula, InStr(sFormula, "(") + 1, InStr(sFormula, ")") - InStr(sFormula, "(") - 1)
            rgblev = Split(sArguments, ",")
            vForm.Interior.Color = RGB(Evaluate(rgblev(0)), Evaluate(rgblev(1)), Evaluate(rgblev(2)))
        End If
    Next vForm
End Sub
```

This worked for formula such as:
`=RGB_print(255,0,255)` and `=RGB_print(A5,B5,C5)`

But again, **find another way** - this code has so many pitfalls I'll probably lose 100 reputation just for posting it.

Comment: Ok, thanks I was looking for a way to map RGB to color display without having to press a button. So if you think of another way I'm all ears

Comment: Conditional formatting?  Not sure what you mean by 'map RGB to colour display'.

Comment: Yes, I mean conditional formatting the actual formula I'm using is "=RGB_print(E9;F9;G9)" and the calling cell is I9

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook - Nice answer. What is the vForm variant actually picking up please? (For Each vForm In rFormula)

Comment: `rFormula` returns a reference to all cells on the sheet containing formula. `vForm` is each cell held in `rFormula`.  Maybe vForm isn't the best naming convention - makes it sound like a user form.  The code will no doubt slow down the more formula you have on the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as an alternative to Darrent's very precise reply, I'm reposting Tim Williwam's comment : whether one may/should mix functions and macros is an important question and it has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433096/using-a-udf-in-excel-to-update-the-worksheet/23437280#23437280). Bottom line is : you can but don't do it unless you know what you are doing and are prepared to face the consequences.