# I am unable to change the value of a cell in my spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel

For some reason I can't change the value using a VBA function in a spreadsheet, I am infuriated at this moment. I have wasted an hour of my life because of this line. Can someone please tell me why it is not working?

```
Public Function GenerateDetailedReport(data As Range)
     Worksheets(5).Cells(2, 2).Value2 = "Maybe"
     GenerateDetailedReport = 1
End Function
```

I keep getting `#VALUE!` error every time I run it. I can read the cell value with no issue, but I cannot change the value.

Comment: I can't see "data" used in your function. it might be the issue.

Comment: data is irrelevant because I am not attempting to use that variable. I am honestly attempting to generate a report that needs to be flexible because it's not a static report.

Comment: There's been a lot of discussion about this and certainly in plain straight answer as Gary pointed out, you can't change a cell value via UDF (*user defined function*). [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433096/using-a-udf-in-excel-to-update-the-worksheet) one post by Tim though that do that however, this is a *use at your own risk* example.

Comment: So a UDF or a user defined SUB is not allowed to change cell values?

Comment: Cell does not need .Value, your basic code in a Sub would be `Sheet5.Cells(2, 1) = "Test"`

Comment: If you want to use the variable "cell" then you need to `Set` it like Gary's Student said below. 

`Dim cell As Range

Set cell = Worksheets(1).Cells(2, 1)
    cell.Value = "Test"`

Answer (score 2):

You can't change a cell value in a function, only return value.

Comment: Then why do all the tutorials show it that way? Can I change it using a Sub instead?

Comment: Yes...use a sub

Comment: I've tried using a sub and this is what I had,

`Public Sub ChangeCell()

    cell = Worksheets(5).Range("A2")
    cell.Value = "Test"
    
End Sub`

Comment: You are missing a **Set**

Comment: Does not work. When I try using the set it gives me a 424 error. I switched it up to this `Worksheet(5).cells(2,1).Value = "test"` and it gives me a **Error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error**

Comment: @Gary if that's all the answer you are going to give, then you should close as a dup rather than answer.  This has been asked and answered countless times