# Get color from conditional formats

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, user-defined-functions

I have this function to get the color which is set by a conditional format.

```
Function ColorIndex(CellColor As Range)
ColorIndex = CellColor.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex
End Function
```

But when I use this function in my worksheet it always returns as #value.

How can I make this work?

Comment: That is exactly the behaviour described in the documentation: [Range.DisplayFormat property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.displayformat). It says also ***"Note that the DisplayFormat property does not work in user defined functions."*** but you actually tried to use it in a user defined function. So it is a feature not a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Dim clrIndex As Integer

Function ColorIndex(CellColor As Range)
    CellColor.Parent.Evaluate "GetColor(" & CellColor.Address(False, False) & ")"
    ColorIndex = clrIndex
End Function

'~~> Get the color index of the cell and store in a temp variable
Sub GetColor(RefCell As Range)
    clrIndex = RefCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex
End Sub
```

[image]

For more explanation you may want to see this amazing [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433096/using-a-udf-in-excel-to-update-the-worksheet) by @TimWilliams

Comment: Thanks this works for me. But now my function is not updating automaticly when i change a value in my sheet. I added the code     "Application.Volatile" on top of your code, but it wont work.

Comment: Add `Application.Volatile` after the line `Function ColorIndex(CellColor As Range)`

Comment: Yes that works but i want to update all the functions i use, and that F2 method only updates that single function

Answer (score 0):

The solution is this:

```
Dim clrIndex As Integer

Function ColorIndex(CellColor As Range)
CellColor.Parent.Evaluate "GetColor(" & CellColor.Address(False, False) & ")"
ColorIndex = clrIndex
End Function

'~~> Get the color index of the cell and store in a temp variable
Sub GetColor(RefCell As Range)
clrIndex = RefCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex
End Sub
```

And for updating the code i use

```
Application.CalculateFullRebuild
```

Thanks @Siddharth Rout