# Macro Running from formula doesn't copy/paste, but running through vbe it works fine

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell in A1 with HYPERLINK formula calling an UDF:

```
=HYPERLINK("#funcCopy()";"macro")
```

The UDF simply copy and paste 3 cells into another location:

```
Public Function funcCopy()
    Set funcCopy = Selection

    Dim plan As Worksheet
    Dim copyrow As Range

    Set plan = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plan1")

    Set copyrow = plan.Range("A3:E3")
    copyrow.Copy plan.Range("A5")
    MsgBox "I'm actually working!"
End Function
```

But when I click on the hyperlink, it just doesn't copy/paste. I add the `MsgBox` to verify if the function is running (and it is!).
Running through VBE works fine.

I'm out of solution to this. Is there something I can do?

Comment: This should be a `Sub`, not a `Function` IMO

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot use a UDF to update a worksheet. There are some cases though like what is posted by Tim [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433096/using-a-udf-in-excel-to-update-the-worksheet), that works.

Comment: You can debug your function by running it from a Sub.

Comment: I have to admit this is a rather clever use of a `Function`. Not a UDF though - a UDF would be invoked from a worksheet formula. If you did `=funcCopy()` in a cell, that cell's value would be `#VALUE!`, because as others have mentioned, a UDF can't modify other cells.

Comment: @urdearboy the function returns a `Variant/Range` (return type is implicit, should be `As Range`), that the `HYPERLINK` formula links to. Change it to `Set funcCopy = Selection.OffSet(1,1)` for extra fun =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Copy` doesn't seem to work, but a direct value transfer does, if that suits your requirements.

```
Public Function funcCopy() As Range
    Set funcCopy = Selection

    Dim plan As Worksheet
    Dim copyrow As Range

    Set plan = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plan1")

    Set copyrow = plan.Range("A3:E3")   
    plan.Range("A5:E5").Value = copyrow.Value

    MsgBox "I'm actually working!"
End Function
```

[image]

(Edited to make the return type explicit, credit goes to [@Mathieu Guindon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1188513/mathieu-guindon) for [pointing that out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55962644/macro-running-from-formula-doesnt-copy-paste-but-running-through-vbe-it-works#comment98577211_55962644).)