# Excel custom function to populate row

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a custom excel function `GetADUser' which takes a Username as input returns several Active Directory Attributes likes Firstname, Surname, SAM Account Name, Distinguished Name.

How can I get these attributes into cells to the left and right of the cell which holds the forumla. ie:

[image]

```
Public Function GetADUser(UserName As String) As String

Dim mycell As Range

Set rootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")

Base = "<LDAP://" & rootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext") & ">"
'filter on user objects with the given account name
fltr = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=Person)" & _
        "(sAMAccountName=" & UserName & "))"
'add other attributes according to your requirements
attr = "distinguishedName,sn,mobile,sAMAccountName,GivenName,l,postOfficeBox"
Scope = "subtree"

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
conn.Open "Active Directory Provider"

Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandText = Base & ";" & fltr & ";" & attr & ";" & Scope

  Set rs = cmd.Execute

  arrPOBox = rs.Fields("postOfficeBox").Value
  Rank = CStr(arrPOBox(0))

  ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = (rs.Fields("sn").Value)
  ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value = (rs.Fields("GivenName").Value)
  ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = (rs.Fields("l").Value)
  ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = (rs.Fields("mobile").Value)

rs.Close
conn.Close

GetADUser = GetADUser

End Function
```

However ActiveCell is not available in Functions.

I did read a way to return a variant instead of String, but it involved CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER to split out the values, which all went to the right of the cell holding the formula. I don't want to make a call to Active Directory for each cell.

Is there a function or procedure that could be implemented such that when a user exits a cell in the username column the other relative cells are populated.

**UPDATE**

This should have been detailed in the original question, but the user name cells could be in any sheet in the Workbook, and not a continuous set of cells in one of four possible columns. (see yellow cells for example)

[image]

The sheet names could also be changed.

The [Intersect method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect) has a limit (30) to the ranges it can take.

I considered regex since the username is always [a-z]{4}[a-z]{2} but then it triggers on every cell.

How would I do the intersect?

Comment: As a general rule, it is not permitted for a *Formula* to modify the contents of other cells.

Comment: A function is a function, i.e. it is supposed to return a value and not modify several cells. What you want here is a macro, not a function. Note that there may be some hacks to make the function modify other cells but that would be, in fact, an hack.

Comment: Oh no... don't start this again! Technically a UDF CAN be used to modify another cell (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433096/using-a-udf-in-excel-to-update-the-worksheet)) but really you shouldn't.

Comment: If your function returns an array you can populate the whole row using it as an array formula (and move your username column to be either end of the row)

Comment: @TimWilliams yes, but I can only populate to the right as opposed to left and right?

Comment: Is it important for username to be where it is?

Comment: Using the Worksheet_Change event might also be a good avenue to explore

Comment: @TimWilliams I am enhancing a very large existing template, moving username is not desirable.

Comment: In that case I'd use a Sub and not a function - the change event would work fine here.

Comment: @Al you would put the formula in range `A2:E2`.  You would write the UDF to return an array with the fields in the position you want.  If updating the template is a big task, write a Sub to do that for you

Comment: @TimWilliams Worksheet_Change ActiveCell returns the new cell address not the cell that is being left?

Comment: The `Target` parameter in the Worksheet_Change events holds the range which got changed - if that range intersects with the UserName column then run your code to update that row/those rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range

    'any updates to username(s)?
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Me.Range("C2:C1000"), Target)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False '<< don't re-trigger the event
        For Each c In rng.Cells
            UpdateAdInfo c  'update the row for this user
        Next c
        Application.EnableEvents = True '<< re-enable events
    End If
End Sub




Public Sub UpdateAdInfo(rngUserName As Range)

    'clear existing data
    rngUserName.EntireRow.Range("A1:B1,D1:E1").ClearContents '<< note range is relative to row, not to sheet

    If Len(rngUserName.Value) = 0 Then Exit Sub 'no username entered, or was deleted

    '...
    '...snipped for clarity: open the recordset using rngUserName.Value
    '...

    Set rs = cmd.Execute

    With rngUserName.EntireRow
        .Cells(1).Value = rs.Fields("GivenName").Value
        .Cells(2).Value = rs.Fields("sn").Value
        'etc etc
    End With

    rs.Close
    conn.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: is there anyway to make Cells(1).Value a relative reference to the original cell that was the target? Like Offset?

Comment: It's already that in the code I posted: every changed cell in ColC is passed to `UpdateAdInfo` as the parameter `rngUserName`, and `rngUserName.EntireRow` represents the specific row for that UserName cell, so `.Cells(1)` is ColA on that row.

Comment: I have used With rngUserName .OffSet(0, -3).Value = etc instead of .Cells(1).Value - this works nicely.