# Change cell formatting

Tags: excel, vba

How can I change formatting of the cell that uses vba function from the code of that function?

Example I tried:

1. made vba module (see code below)
2. put in excel sheet in some cell "=test()"
3. function "works" - it changes cell value and shows 2 popup windows. But formatting stays the same

```
Function test()
    MsgBox (Application.ThisCell.NumberFormat)        ' shows "General"
    Application.ThisCell.NumberFormat = "Currency"
    'Application.ThisCell.NumberFormat = "#,##0_);[Red](#,##0)"
    MsgBox (Application.ThisCell.NumberFormat)        ' still shows "General"
    
    test = 12345.6
End Function
```

How to make it work?

(I need custom formatting rule, not "currency", but custom rule (test example in commented line) doesn't work too)

Comment: A User-Defined Function in a cell *can't* change the sheet formatting, except in some edge cases. It's not meant to be used to try changing the format, but just to return the value to the cell.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel

Comment: Seems you're  just hard-coding a format not based on anything. Just set the formatting another way. You *can* write something to do that. Write a Sub that you call from a button on the worksheet or...somewhere else.

Comment: Workaround - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433096/using-a-udf-in-excel-to-update-the-worksheet/23437280#23437280

Answer (score 0):

Please don't kill me for this wacko solution :-)

I have created a function, resulting in the number 4096:

```
Function very_weird_UDF()
  very_weird_UDF = 4096
End Function
```

Then I have created a conditional formatting rule, based on the present of that UDF (User-Defined Function) inside the formulatext of that cell, as you can see here:

Conditional formatting's formula: `=FIND("very_weird_UDF",FORMULATEXT((B2)))`

Screenshot of what it looks like:

[image]

For your information:
Cell "C3" contains the formula, the other cells in B2:C5 just contain the value 4096.
Cells E2:F5 contain the mentioned `=Find(...)` formula.

Oh, if you wonder why I use such a weird name for the UDF? Just imagine I used a simpler name, like 'a' or 'f' or something like that. That might highlight a lot of cells who don't use that formula (like a simple `=If(...)` or an `=And(...)` or ...