# What is the proper way to pass a cell as a parameter in a UDF in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, parameter-passing, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to create a UDF which takes the value of a referenced cell, tests that value against a range, and depending on whether it fits within the range, will result in an "X" or an "O". Here's the only way I can get it to work:

**Code:**

```
Public Function ASE(cellRef As Variant)

    Dim setpointU As Integer, setpointL As Integer
    Dim enabled As String, disabled As String

    cellValue = Range(cellRef).Value
    setpointL = 50
    setpointU = 100
    enabled = "O"
    disabled = "X"

        If cellValue >= setpointL Or cellValue <= setpontU Then
            ASE = enabled
        Else
            ASE = disabled
        End If

End Function
```

**Function in the Formula Bar:** =AsE("D7") //(it automatically makes the s lowercase, for some reason)
**Result:** X
**Other info that may be useful:** the value of D7 is **24**, which is coming from the cell's function, **=VALUE(Imported!B5)**

To elaborate, the ONLY WAY I can get it to technically work is when two conditions are met: 1) when I use quotation marks in the function around the referenced cell, and 2) when the parameter cellRef is Variant. If I do not use quotation marks [=ASE(D7) instead of =ASE("D7")], it does not work. If I change cellRef's data type to Range or String, it does not work. It will only return the **#VALUE!** error.

How am I supposed to format this so that I do not have to use quotations around the referenced cell?

Comment: to answer your question about work arounds from your now deleted other Q, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433096/using-a-udf-in-excel-to-update-the-worksheet)

Comment: @chrisneilsen Thank you, for finding me and sharing that link. After running into similar questions with the same answer, I deleted it for the sake of redundancy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass the cell itself (with no quotes):

```
Public Function ASE(cellRef As Range)

    Dim setpointU As Integer, setpointL As Integer
    Dim enabled As String, disabled As String

    cellValue = cellRef.Value
    setpointL = 50
    setpointU = 100
    enabled = "O"
    disabled = "X"

        If cellValue >= setpointL Or cellValue <= setpointU Then
            ASE = enabled
        Else
            ASE = disabled
        End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

You are up against two trouble makers and a few problems.

One is a memory your worksheet has of the capitalization of AsE. It's a problem I have come across frequently and I have no idea how to cure it. Even if I give the function another name, save, close Excel, restart, and change the name back, Excel will remember the wrong capitalization. So, what I do is to change the name permanently.

The other is in the ambiguity of `cellRef As Variant`. As you know, a variant could be anything and Excel, it seems, doesn't make up its mind until it hits `cellValue = Range(cellRef).Value`. At that moment it needs to be a string and, therefore, embraced by quotation marks. D7 is a range, of course. But then `cellValue = Range(cellRef).Value`doesn't make sense. It should be `cellValue = cellRef.Value` if `cellRef` is a range. You left the choice to Excel and, admit it, it did its best under the circumstances.

There is a problem with the missing `Option Explicit` at the top of your code. It would alert you to the missing declaration of `cellValue` and the misspelling in the variable name at `Or cellValue <= setpontU Then`. Open the *Tools* menu of the VB Editor. Select the *Editor* tab from the *Options* menu and check "Require variable declaration". VBA will automatically insert `Option Explicit` in all code sheets created thereafter. Only then may you safely forget about it.

Finally, please bear in mind that the return of a function also must have a data type. Since you don't declare any the return will be a variant. Obviously, your function returns a string. Yes, Excel and VBA will sort it out. But they could do better with a little cooperation from you. At least you could share what you know. Once you do that your code might look like this.

```
Function ASE(cellRef As Range) As String

    Dim cellValue As Variant
    Dim upperSetpoint As Integer, lowerSetpoint As Integer

    cellValue = cellRef.Value
    lowerSetpoint = 50
    upperSetpoint = 100

    If cellValue >= lowerSetpoint And cellValue <= upperSetpoint Then
        ASE = "O"                   ' enabled
    Else
        ASE = "X"                   ' disabled
    End If
End Function
```

Note that the logical error in your condition has also been found. Any value must be either >=SetpointL or <=setpointU. Therefore your function can't return anything but "O". It's different if you apply both conditions as prerequisite using the logical `And`.

As a closing note, all procedures are "Public" unless they are declared as "Private". What then is the point of declaring a procedure as "Public"? It's much clearer to only mark those which are **not** "Public".

Comment: Trust me, I was wondering about a lot of the things you mentioned as well, but I know the questions need to stay a bit more focused on Stack Overflow, so I stuck with the #1 issue. That being said, I'm really thankful you took the time to give explanations and answer all the "why's" for me, and point out those obvious syntax/logic errors. Thank you, great info!