# #VALUE error when setting Interior.ColorIndex with Sub called from UDF

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I've tried searching for the answer to my problem, which is setting the color of a cell in Excel with a UDF. The initial issue is that Interior.ColorIndex cannot be called from a UDF, and the workaround provided was to make a Sub that did, and then call that from the UDF. So, I wrote

```
Function colorChanger(cell As Range) As String
     Call cellBackgroundChanger(cell)
     colorChanger = "hello world"
End Function
```

```
Sub cellBackgroundChanger(cell As Range)
     cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
End Sub
```

I have also tried

```
Sub cellBackgroundChanger(cell As Range)
     Range(cell).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
End Sub
```

out of desperation and being new to VBA. Either way, the function just returns a #VALUE! error to the cell. I know a UDF may seem stupid to use here, but I would really prefer to do so for other reasons. Any help would be appreciated, sorry if this has been asked before.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433096/using-a-udf-in-excel-to-update-the-worksheet

Comment: User-Defined Functions take inputs and return a value to a cell - they don't manipulate worksheets and/or format cells. If you absolutely need a cell-altering UDF, use the linked code at your own risks.