# Assign cell color function

Tags: excel, vba

trying to create a function that colour a cells interior (using RGB) according to user input and coded below, can't understand why this is not working though, can anyone advise,

```
Function RGBC(r, g, b)

Dim src As Range

Set src = Application.ThisCell

With src
.Interior.Color = RGB(r, g, b)
End With
 
End Function
```

Comment: A function called from the worksheet cannot change the format of a cell including the one that calls it.

Comment: now there are workarounds that are tricky to implement and maintain: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433096/using-a-udf-in-excel-to-update-the-worksheet

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround to the inability to call directly is to load relevant data into a global variable/type then use a caller function (in this case SheetCalculate) to fire the event you want. For eg.

> ThisWorkbook Code

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Call ColorRGB
End Sub
```

> Module Code

```
Private Type RangeRGB
    Update As Boolean
    WS As String
    RNG As String
    RGBColor As Long
End Type

Private tRGB As RangeRGB

Public Function RGBColor(R As Long, G As Long, B As Long)
    On Error GoTo ExitFunction
    tRGB.RNG = Application.Caller.Address
    tRGB.WS = Application.Caller.Worksheet.Name
    tRGB.RGBColor = RGB(R, G, B)
    tRGB.Update = True
ExitFunction:
End Function

Function ColorRGB()
    On Error GoTo ExitFunction
    If tRGB.Update = True Then
        With Worksheets(tRGB.WS)
            Range(tRGB.RNG).Interior.Color = tRGB.RGBColor
        End With
        tRGB.WS = ""
        tRGB.RNG = ""
        tRGB.Update = False
    End If
ExitFunction:
End Function
```

Please note that if you delete the function from the sheet though, no update is performed