# Error when resizing ListObject in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to resize a table using VBA using this code:

```
Function MirrorTable()
    Dim testTbl As ListObject
    Set testTbl = Sheets("Testing").ListObjects(1)
    
    MsgBox testTbl.Range.Address
    
    testTbl.Resize testTbl.Range.Resize(15)
End Function
```

If I execute this function by writing `=MirrorTable()` into a cell the message box is displayed correctly, but then I get an `#VALUE` in the cell and the table is not resized. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: [A user-defined function called by a formula in a worksheet cell cannot change the environment of Microsoft Excel.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/170787) The statement is [not entirely true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433096/using-a-udf-in-excel-to-update-the-worksheet) though but one should avoid changing the environment of Microsoft Excel using a UDF.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thank you! How would recommend me to call my function?

Comment: Create a proc in a module and then run the macro from the developer tab? You can also insert a form control in the worksheet and run the macro from there?