# Excel VBA UDF to change value of multiple cells

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I am working on an Excel project and I wanted to implement a UDF to change the value of multiple cells. I tried the following code I found on another thread to change value on an adjacent cell, so I played a bit around with the Offset parameters:

```
Function clear_it()

Dim pas As String
pas = "Call del(" & Application.Caller.Offset(0 , 6).Address(False, False) & ")"
Evaluate pas

End Function

'---------------------------

Sub del(rng As Range)
rng = 0
End Sub
```

**This code worked as intended and it "deleted" the cell which was 6 places to the right by setting its value to 0!**

Following the same logic, I tried the following code to delete multiple cells on the same column:

```
Function clear_it()

Dim pas As String
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To 5

pas = "Call del(" & Application.Caller.Offset(0 + i, 6).Address(False, False) & ")"
Evaluate pas

Next i

End Function

'---------------------------------------

Sub del(rng As Range)
rng = 0
End Sub
```

**However this code just crashed my Excel Workbook and it bricked it. The file was just restarting and crashing on an infinite loop and I could not access the code to change it. So I had to delete the file permanently.**

To clarify my intentions:

*I have a column of data. When I set a particular cell to 0, I want 5 cells beneath it to also become 0 automatically, without pressing a button or something like that, so I wanted to create something like an If formula 6 cells to the left which calls my function:*

`=IF(J6 = 0; clear_it();0)`

To further clarify my attempts:

*I have only tested it by putting the above condition on a single cell, hence an infinite loop by recursive 0 valued cells is not possible.*

Can anyone perhaps help me on what the problem might be or if I am trying something I shouldn`t with the UDF behaviour? Or is my approach to this problem totally wrong and there is a simpler way to do this on Excel?

Comment: Entered in cell J6 =IF($J$5=0,0,K6) so either the value of k6 or 0 based on the value of j5 then drag down as far as.

Comment: The code works just fine for me. However, I would recommend not to use this approach. UDF is not intended to change values of another cell. It was never meant to be used that way. What you are doing is sort of a hack as shown [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433096/using-a-udf-in-excel-to-update-the-worksheet) as well. You can use `Worksheet_Change` event to handle that. More about the event is mentioned [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/why-ms-excel-crashes-and-closes-during-worksheet-change-sub-procedure)