# VBA - Change cell background color

Tags: excel, vba, colors

I've been building a team vacation calendar in Excel (Office 365 version) and I'm using VBA for the first time to automate some calculations and styling.

I've been stuck on the following:

I want to create a function that changes the background color of a cell.
I have four colors to switch between so I'd rather make four functions, one per color.
That function will then be called within different functions when needed.
I don't want to use ColorIndex, but rather a custom color (I can use RGB or the Long value), but I can't get the ColorIndex to work either.

My assumption is that the problem lies with the range but at this point, who knows :D.

The long values of each color are stored within a self-made Enum "OwnColorLong".

Here are some of my tries, every time the result in my Excel sheet (when running as a formula) is "#Value!".

```
'Function SetBackgroundToRed(RangeToChange As Range)
'    Dim ColorIWant As Long
'    ColorIWant = OwnColorLong.Red         
'    RangeToChange.Interior.Color = ColorIWant 
'End Function

'Sub SetColorToRed(RangeToChange As Range)
'    RangeToChange.Select
'    With Selection.Interior
'        .ColorIndex = 3
'    End With
'End Sub
'
Function SetBackgroundToRed(RangeToChange As Range)
   Dim MyRange As Range
   Set MyRange = Worksheets("Vacation Calendar").Range("RangeToChange")
    MyRange.Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .ColorIndex = 3
    End With
End Function
```

I'm still a bit confused about when to use a sub or a function, or when to best use a class module.  All code is now placed within one module, I'll be writing a Main sub linked to a button and putting all the code in there except for the functions themselves.  If there are better practices, feel free to let me know.

Comment: Better to use this as a Sub and run from a button.

Comment: Hi Ben,
I'm not sure if using a button is the best way to go here, since I want to use these functions within different functions.  The color change is just a small part of the code I'm planning to write.  I'm going to use this within IF-statements for example.

I made one button in the sheet and that should run all calculations and update the colors for clarity.

Comment: Don't really understand why a button wouldn't work. Also doesn't make sense to not use the function's argument.

Comment: Still make it a Sub since it does something and doesn't return anything.

Comment: SJR, how am i not using the function's argument? That's the range of cells that need the new color. I thought I was selecting that range and then changing the color, could be wrong tho :)
I could make it a sub, but I've been trying everything :p  second example is a sub and that didn't work either.  I'll make sure to make it a sub in the final version :)
I can't make it a button since I won't be using this sub in the sheet, It's going to be hidden in different functions. The color change is not the main goal of my code, although important for a quick view for the end user who opens the sheet

Comment: Why not using conditional formatting ?

Comment: `"RangeToChange"` is not the same as `RangeToChange`. The former is a `String`, the latter is a `Range`.

Comment: Hi Patrick,  I'm hoping to avoid it, just for cleanlines in my code.  It is the backup tho :)

Comment: I found an example somewhere where in they used .Range("A1") (see third example in original question)
I found it strange as well, but trying everything :)

Answer (score 1):

- This won't work as a UDF called from a worksheet cell. Except for some edge cases, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433096/using-a-udf-in-excel-to-update-the-worksheet), UDFs called from a cell [can't modify other cells on the worksheet](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel-f2f0ce5d-8ea5-6ce7-fddc-79d36192b7a1).

  > Functions can perform a calculation that returns either a value or text to the cell that they are entered in. Any environmental changes should be made through the use of a Visual Basic subroutine.
- Prefer `Sub` to `Function` since this does something and doesn't return anything.
- "I have four colors to switch between so I'd rather make four functions, one per color" - better to make *one* function and pass a color parameter.

```
Private Sub SetColor(ByVal RangeToChange As Range, ByVal Color As Long)
    RangeToChange.Interior.Color = Color
End Sub
```

Called like

```
SetColor yourRange, OwnColorLong.Red
```

Answer (score 0):

Second, `Sub` or `Function`? If you need an answer from your method, then `Function` it is. In your case, you need no answer, so it is `Sub`.

```
Sub SetBackgroundToRed(RangeToChange As Range)
    With RangeToChange.Interior
        .ColorIndex = 3
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Sam,
Thanks!
The cells will be looped over and checked for conditions, that will decide the range, so unfortunately not the selected cells :/

Comment: I have changed above

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work eventually!

```
Dim rng As String
rng = "A1"
Range(rng).Interior.Color = OwnColorLong.Red
```

The problem was not knowing how to pass a range as a variable, I had to use String apparently, not Range.

Thanks everyone for the help!