# Adding a comment in a cell based on another cell's value

Tags: excel, vba, function, if-statement

I want to add a comment into comment section of a cell based on another cell's value.

For example: the value of *F2 cell* is "High Level" and by a function like `=GetComment(F2)` the comment section of *B2 cell* changed to "High Level".

If the value of *F2 cell* is empty, "Nothing" should be add into comment section of *B2 cell*.

```vb
Function GetComment(ByVal target As Range, rng As Range)
    If IsEmpty(rng.Value) Then
        target.AddComment ("Nothing")
    Else
        target.AddComment (rng.Value)
    End If
End Function
```

Capture of Excel environment:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a UDF in Excel to update the worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433096/using-a-udf-in-excel-to-update-the-worksheet)

Comment: @Storax - Thank you for your response, but it really did not answer my question. My exact issue is accessing the comment section of a cell and changing it based on another cell's value.

Comment: According to the picture  in the post you placed the function `GetComment` into cell B2 and I assume your expectation is that based on the value in F2 the comment in B2 will change accordingly. So, in other words you use a UDF to do that, right?

Comment: @Storax - yes, my expectation is same what you said, I changed the comment of cell B2 manually to better show the my purpose.
actually the Function in cell B2 does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not use a UDF then you need to change your code like that

```
Option Explicit

Function GetComment(ByVal target As Range, rng As Range)
    If IsEmpty(rng.Value) Then
        myCmt target, "Nothing"
        'target.AddComment ("Nothing")   <= This code will fail if a comment already exists
    Else
        myCmt target, rng.Value
        'target.AddComment (rng.Value)   <= This code will fail if a comment already exists
    End If
End Function

Function myCmt(rg As Range, cmt As String)
' This will add  the string cmt as a comment to the target
' and will delete any existing comment regardless
    
    ' Just delete any existing comment
    If Not rg.Comment Is Nothing Then
        rg.Comment.Delete
    End If
    rg.AddComment (cmt)

End Function


Sub TestIt()
    GetComment [B2], [F2]
End Sub
```

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433096/using-a-udf-in-excel-to-update-the-worksheet) you find a workaround how to use an UDF in such a case.