# Assigning value to Interior.Color fails and gives #VALUE error where Font.Color does not

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make an easy way to dynamically change the fill color of cells based on RGB values supplied., but I can't get the most fundamental line of code to work.

```
Function colorCells(cellsToPaint As Range, rInt As Integer, gInt As Integer, bInt As Integer)
    
    Call setFill(cellsToPaint, rInt, gInt, bInt)
    
    colorCells = ""
    
End Function

Sub setFill(targetCells As Range, r As Integer, g As Integer, b As Integer)
    
    targetCells.Interior.Color = RGB(r, g, b)
        
End Sub
```

Entering `=colorCells(I8,0,0,255)` into a cell with the code above doesn't alter cell I8 and gives #VALUE error in the current cell.

```
Function colorCells(cellsToPaint As Range, rInt As Integer, gInt As Integer, bInt As Integer)
    
    Call setFill(cellsToPaint, rInt, gInt, bInt)
    
    colorCells = ""
    
End Function

Sub setFill(targetCells As Range, r As Integer, g As Integer, b As Integer)
    
    targetCells.Font.Color = RGB(r, g, b)
        
End Sub
```

What's boggling is that entering `=colorCells(I8,0,0,255)` into a cell with the code above (with `Font` replacing `Interior`) DOES work, changing the font color of cell I8 to blue and returning "" to the current cell.

Comment: Note that UDFs are generally not meant to be (ab)used in this way, e.g. to modify some other cell(s). UDFs should generally just return a value to the cell they are called from.

Comment: But after that caveat, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433096/using-a-udf-in-excel-to-update-the-worksheet) for one approach.

Comment: `Call setFillColor` but the sub is named `Sub setFill`. I'm surprised the font was able to change, was it just a mistake when copying the code over to the post?

Comment: In "=colorCells(I8,0,0,255)" the 'I8' is a variable called I8 and not a cell range. To provide the range I8 you would need "=colorCells(ThisWorkSheet.range("I8"),0,0,255)"

Comment: try, `Range(targetCells).Interior.Color = RGB(r, g, b)`

Comment: @BigBen that's what I ended up using and it worked, though I'm still not sure why. I am trying to dynamically change the fill color of cells based on table RGB values (makes it really easy to generate color palettes/hue/shades). If you know of a different code structure that works better, I'm all ears.

Comment: @Toddleson You are correct. I've created a lot of similarly named procedures through all the troubleshooting. I neglected changing the calling line before making the post.