Putting simple value to the cell of the spreadsheet using VBA -code
This is frustating.  I am trying to put values to the cells of the sheet using VBA -code calculations
The simple function as an example below
Function Testi_5(alue As Range) As Integer

Cells(1, 1) = "Hello World"

Testi_5 = 1
End Function

gives the same results, no matter I am trying (wrong datatype).
Pls check the image below


You'll find that it works if you comment out the Cells(1,1... line as for (almost) all intents and purposes formulas cannot put things into other cells. What purpose does it serve anyway?

Trying to put some values to cells.  The code is only an example, it serves no other purpose.   The beef is:  put value to cell(1,1)

Why are you using a Function?

In general, Functions called from a cell in the worksheet cannot affect changes to other cells beside the one that calls the function.

If you want to write something to cell(1, 1), do so - just not with a UDF that you call from another cell. Excel forbids such behavior, the execution of the macro is stopped and you get the #Value-error in the Excel sheet. If you put a formula like =Sum(D:D) or =Sin(F2) into a cell, you don't expect that all of a sudden another cell is modified, and that's true also for user defined functions. Instead, use a regular Sub or Function and make up your mind how it is triggered.

If I use sub -definition, it works but how do I pass the range to sub as a parameter from excel ?

How do you want to trigger the code? Using a button? Using a change event? Using the Macro-Menu from Excel? What range do you want to pass (how do you know?)

If you want an example of doing it through a function see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433096/using-a-udf-in-excel-to-update-the-worksheet/23437280#23437280  But as stated this may not be the best method and there are many many methods that do not require this bootstrapping.

Reference: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel-f2f0ce5d-8ea5-6ce7-fddc-79d36192b7a1#:~:text=A%20user%2Ddefined%20function%20called,Change%20another%20cell's%20value.

Sub Testi_5()
  Range([A1]) = "Hello World"
End Sub

Put the destination in A1, for e.g.: A1="C21:C43" (without quotes). Then run Testi_5 (Alt+F8).
Explanation.

[A1] provides its value "C21:C43".
Range([A1]) refers to C21:C43.
"Hello World" comes to the range C21:C43.



Learning excel-vba free eBook (PDF)

Excel® VBA Notes for Professionals book

Getting started with VBA in Office

But your start point is "Developer tab --> Record Macro". Enable macro recording, act, stop macro recording, learn VBA code.

[A1] is already a range, so you can write [A1] = "Hello World". Or you can write Range("A1") =  "Hello World". You can't use Range([A1]), that's invalid. What is not nice (in both variants) is that the code relies on the Active Sheet. Furthermore, this doesn't address the problem that the OP uses the function as UDF. Writing to a cell in a function is perfectly valid, only when using the function as UDF it is no longer valid.

@FunThomas May be, you will check it first?

What do you mean with check it first? Range([A1]) = "Hello World" gives a runtime error 1004.

Ah, now I understand what you're after, you want a kind of "indirect" function. Put an address in A1 and write something to that address. Okay, that kind of works. But honestly: What is the idea of that? I am doing VBA programming since a looong time, and I have a hard time to get a use case for that. I guess the OP is after something much more simple.

@FunThomas I just answer the question. The ideas are behind of OP. The XY problem meets very often, but Petri told he learns Excel and VBA.

@FunThomas Sorry if I was too stern. I am always happy to have useful discussions.
