# Is it possible to output VBA formula as rich text in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I know that there is a possibility to copy text to a new cell and apply formatting to it.
But desirable result is to get formatted text in the same cell.

I have a VBA function, which makes some text replacements:
How it looks like in excel cell: `=formStepDescription([@[Step Template]];[@[ST Parameters]];parameters;$A$1)`
But it's output is plain text and I need to highlight my substitutions.
The point is that parameters might change and formula should recalculate dynamically.

```
Function formStepDescription(stepDescriptionTemplate As Range, STParameters, tableWithValues As Range, mode)
    Dim stubsList() As String
    Dim parametersList() As String
    Dim valuesList() As String

    If STParameters = "" Then
        formStepDescription = stepDescriptionTemplate
    Else
        stubsList() = Filter(Split(stepDescriptionTemplate), "#param")
        parametersList() = Split(STParameters, Chr(10))
        valuesList = getValuesByIDs(parametersList, tableWithValues, mode)
        formStepDescription = stepDescription(stepDescriptionTemplate, valuesList, stubsList)
    End If
End Function
Private Function stepDescription(stepDescriptionTemplate, valuesList() As String, stubsList() As String)
    Dim stepDescriptionText As String

    stepDescriptionText = stepDescriptionTemplate

    For i = 0 To UBound(valuesList)
        stepDescriptionText = Replace(stepDescriptionText, stubsList(i), valuesList(i))
    Next

    stepDescription = stepDescriptionText
End Function
```

Comment: of course its possible using vba, but I assume you are not looking for that?

Comment: @StevenMartin I am looking for any kind of solution, actually :)

Comment: Can you post a sample of what you want, you can always use conditional formatting with formulas to do things like bold and colours , if you need parts of a string formatted , then vba is needed

Comment: @StevenMartin added some details in question.

Comment: Can you post the vba function, you will need to make the changes in the function using   .font.color etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel User Defined Function: change the cell's color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705663/excel-user-defined-function-change-the-cells-color)

Comment: @ScottCraner, He shows how to change other cells, but I need to apply rich text formatting for the cell with UDF