# Copy Cell Backgroundcolor

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I'm using Excel 2013 and I want to write a Function in VBA that has two Parameters (Sourcecell and Destinationcell) and simply copies the Backgroundcolor from Sourcecell to the Destinationcell. This is what I have:

```
Function setRGB2(ByVal sCell As Range, ByVal dCell As Range)
Dim lngColor As Long
Dim B As Long
Dim G As Long
Dim R As Long

On Error GoTo Fehler

lngColor = sCell.Interior.Color
B = lngColor / 65536
G = (lngColor - B * 65536) / 256
R = lngColor - B * 65536 - G * 256

Range(dCell).Interior.Color = RGB(R, G, B)
'Range(dCell).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(R, G, B)

Fehler:
    With Err

    End With
End Function
```

I get the Error:

> improper use of a property

For Example my Sourcecell is B16 and my Destinationcell is B46. So in B46 I write `=setRGB2($B$16;B46)`. I tried setting the Color directly like `dCell.Interior.Color = sCell.Interior.Color` but that didn't work.

**EDIT**

I have added the Declaration for the Parameters. But it seems to be another Problem. Even if I do `dCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 1` it throws the same error.

Comment: How are you using this function and why don't you just assign the `Interior.Color` of one cell to the other directly?

Comment: Why don't you just use `Range(dCell).Interior.Color = sCell.Interior.Color`? Why so complicated? Also specify a type for your `sCell, dCell` in `setRGB2(sCell, dCell)`

Comment: Please declare sCell and dCell, so we know what we are talking about. Please also make sure that R is greater than 0, please have a look at [RGB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/rgb-function)

Comment: Remember to check for the default no-colour, when `sCell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User Defined Functions cannot change the state of worksheet/cells. In other words, cannot change colors. ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705663/excel-user-defined-function-change-the-cells-color))

But Subs can do, so you can design a Function and then call the function from the Sub.

But in your case, a Sub with parameters should do and you can call it in your VBA code whenever you want, in an easy way.

```
Sub testing()

setRGB2 [A1], [A2]

End Sub

Private Sub setRGB2(ByRef sCell As Range, ByRef dCell As Range)

dCell.Interior.Color = sCell.Interior.Color
End Sub
```

Also, I said at start of my answer that an UDF cannot change the state of a worksheet, but if for any reason you really need it, there is a way to do it in a really complex and hardcore way.

> [UDF to change cells
>   color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520732/i-dont-want-my-excel-add-in-to-return-an-array-instead-i-need-a-udf-to-change)

Also, in your question you say:

*For Example my Sourcecell is B16 and my Destinationcell is B46. So in B46 I write `=setRGB2($B$16;B46)`*

This is wrong because you are creating a circular reference, and that's causing you an error.

> [More about circular
>   references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/remove-or-allow-a-circular-reference-8540bd0f-6e97-4483-bcf7-1b49cd50d123)

Comment: Nice find on the UDF to change the colour of a cell!  There's also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433096/using-a-udf-in-excel-to-update-the-worksheet) link buried in there which might be easier to implement?

Comment: I was guessing something along the lines. Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to achieve with the function but the follwoing code should be correct, at least syntactically

```
Option Explicit

Function setRGB2(ByVal sCell As Range, ByVal dCell As Range)
    Dim lngColor As Long
    Dim B As Long
    Dim G As Long
    Dim R As Long

'    On Error GoTo Fehler

    lngColor = sCell.Interior.Color
    B = WorksheetFunction.Max(lngColor / 65536, 0)
    G = WorksheetFunction.Max((lngColor - B * 65536) / 256, 0)
    R = WorksheetFunction.Max(lngColor - B * 65536 - G * 256, 0)

    dCell.Interior.Color = RGB(R, G, B)
    'Range(dCell).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(R, G, B)

    Exit Function

Fehler:
    With Err

    End With
End Function

Sub TestIt()
    setRGB2 Range("A1"), Range("A2")
End Sub
```

Comment: The RGB split is unneccessary, but it's *far* easier with [Bitwise Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/operators-and-expressions/logical-and-bitwise-operators): `B = (lngColor AND rgbBlue)/65536: G=(lngColor AND rgbLime)/256: R=(lngColor AND rgbRed)`

Comment: I would say, just `dCell.Interior.Color = sCell.Interior.Color`should be sufficient.

Comment: Yeah, as I said, the RGB split is unneccessary.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the cell *has* a colour first, and if so then just copy it:

```vb
Public Sub CopyColour(ByRef Source As Range, ByRef Destination As Range)
    If Source.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone Then
        Destination.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
    Else
        Destination.Interior.Color = Source.Interior.Color
    End If
End Sub
```

Doesn't manage gradients or patterns.