# Extracting value from a cell containing string after particular word

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a big excel file where in one column it contains Json as shown below:

```
""wrtieSeg"": {
    ""ValueName"": ""Type1"",
    ""Div"": ""45"",
    ""Date"": ""08/06/2017"",
    ""fig"": ""0-100""
  },
  ""readSeg"": {
    ""ValueName"": ""Type2"",
    ""Div"": ""45"",
    ""Date"": ""08/06/2017"",
    ""fig"": ""980""
  }
```

Now i have two columns (`Type1` and `Type2`) in my excel sheet where i want `fig` value like (i.e `0-100`) in `Type1` column, and `fig` value like (i.e `980`) in `Type2` column.

Comment: Excel by itself is a poor choice to be doing this.  You need a JSON parser.  VBA probably has support for this, so do it there.

Comment: I am a little confused as to the layout but can you read the JSON into a JSON object using https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON and then simply parse the object for the fig elements? It is easy I am just not sure where I am getting the JSON from and is it properly formed? I'd say with that snippet alone it would be impossible to say how you would extract definitively (but someone may contradict me)

Comment: Are these double double-quotes stored as they are in Excel?

Comment: The JSON as it stands is not properly formed so maybe just use traditional split function to extract ? Read in value from sheet and use Split to isolate ""fig""

Answer (score 0):

Since your JSON is quite basic, little helper function and main function should be enough to parse it. Note that you don't have valid JSON in your example, as it's lacking closing bracket `}`. I added it in my example (and also edited your question to be correct).

**This code you have to define in `Module` in your `VBAProject`** ([reference how to call VBA functions from sheet cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601630/how-to-call-vba-function-from-excel-cells)). Now, if your JSON is located in `A1` cell and you want to extract value for `Type1`, then you have to use such formula: `=ExtractFromJson(A1, "Type1")`.

```
Option Explicit
Public Function ExtractFromJson(json As String, valueName As String)
    'declare variables needed
    Dim elementStartIndex As Long, elementEndIndex As Long, element As String
    'loop through json, extracting elements
    Do While InStr(elementStartIndex + 1, json, "{") > 0
        'locate element by searching { and }
        elementStartIndex = InStr(elementStartIndex + 1, json, "{")
        elementEndIndex = InStr(elementStartIndex + 1, json, "}")
        'extract element and pass it to function
        element = Mid(json, elementStartIndex, elementEndIndex -  elementStartIndex + 1)
        ExtractFromJson = ParseElement(element, valueName)

        If ExtractFromJson <> "" Then
            Exit Function
        End If
    Loop
End Function

Function ParseElement(element As String, valueName As String) As String
    Dim valueNameIndex As Long
    'locate variable with specified name and take its value
    valueNameIndex = InStr(1, element, """""ValueName"""":") + 14
    If valueName = Trim(Replace(Mid(element, valueNameIndex, InStr(valueNameIndex, element, ",") - valueNameIndex), """", "")) Then
        valueNameIndex = InStr(1, element, """""fig"""":") + 8
        ParseElement = Trim(Replace(Mid(element, valueNameIndex, InStr(valueNameIndex, element, "}") - valueNameIndex), """", ""))
        Exit Function
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Turczyn Thanks, but i want function something like `=ParseElement("Type1","A1)` than it give me value for Type1.

Comment: @Roy1245 Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

you could use:

```
Function ParseElement(myType As String, A1 As Variant)
    Dim v As Variant

    v = Split(Mid(A1, InStr(A1, myType)), """")

    ParseElement = v(Application.Match("fig", v, 0) + 3)
End Function
```

you may add some error handling should the user pass wrong `myType` parameter or the Json cell not contain it

Comment: Not working properly, since i have json data in almost 25000 rows.

Comment: I don't get you. You may want to edit and enhance your question so as to give all proper detals

Comment: I have a big json file in an excel sheet where for each unique identifier cell i have one json. I want the extract only two `fig` value where `ValueName` is `Type1` and `ValueName` is `Type2`.

Comment: and what would have it to do with _"Not working properly, since i have json data in almost 25000 rows"_?