# Function to split a string into multiple characters

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a custom function that takes the selected parameter and splits its content on different cells.

example :

`A1=ABCDE`

becomes

`B1=A, C1=B, D1=C, E1=D, F1=E`

so this is what I tried :

```
Function SplitWord(Word)
NbCar = Len(Word) // get the number of cardinals of the text
SplitWord = Left(Word, 1) // put the first letter in the cell that called the function
t = NbCar - 1
For i = 1 To t
ActiveCell.Offset(0, i) = Right(Left(Word, i), 1)
Next
End Function
```

Comment: A VBA user-defined-function can't change the values of other cells. Maybe you can use a WorkSheet_Change event instead, or just keep the original value in column A and use Excel formulas in other columns to hold the separate letters. As a side note, try using the `Mid` function, instead of `Left` and `Right`.

Answer (score 5):

1. Enter the contents to split in cell A1.
2. Paste this in cell B1: **=MID($A$1,COLUMN()-COLUMN($B$1)+1,1)**
3. Drag to the right

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this with simple Excel formulas - place this cell in B1 and copy it to C1-F1:

```
=MID(A1,COLUMN()-COLUMN($B$1)+1,1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `=MID($A1,COLUMNS($A$1:A$1),1)`, then drag it left it shall come.

Answer (score 1):

1) Place text you want to split in cell A1 ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lc1SX.jpg))

2) Then paste this function into any cell you want ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4g7YM.jpg))

```
=MID($A1;COLUMN(A1)-COLUMN($A1)+1;1)
```

3) Move the mouse cursor over the little block in the lower right corner of the cell in which you pasted the above-mentioned function ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DM1L.jpg))

4) Click and hold on the fill handle, and drag to the right to fill in the series ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsDLL.jpg))

Comment: This seems to be the same answer @rbhattad gave.
And I would recommend refraining from this profuse usage of images outside of SO.

Comment: @Scorpioo590 Although I agree 100% with your opinion that this is a 'duplicate' answer, please bear in mind the "i.stack.imgur.com" is the site that SO uses for both linked and embedded images.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify cells in UDF, when calling this UDF from sheet (actually there is possible ways, but they're sophisticated and I don't recomend to use them). You can use this funciton instead:

```
Function SplitWord(Word As String) As String()
    Dim res() As String
    ReDim res(1 To Len(Word))
    For i = 1 To Len(Word)
        res(i) = Mid(Word, i, 1)
    Next
    SplitWord = res
End Function
```

---

**How to use it:**

1. Select destination range (e.g. `B1:F1`)
2. *With selected range* enter formula in formula bar `=SplitWord(A1)`
3. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it

If your destination range in one column (e.g. `B1:B5`) use `=TRANSPOSE(SplitWord(A1))`

Comment: not really working it renders the 1st letter only unfortunatly

Comment: is there any way to get a variable inside a function to be a global variable ?

Comment: have you selected B1:F1 and pressed CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER as I wrote?

Comment: works perfect .. but i don't wanna select anything
because i have a list of words and each word contains a different number of letters
so it wouldn't be useful to do the same for all words !

Comment: should it be necessary user defined function or macro will fit too?

Comment: i was hoping i could make a function but .. ok i will try a macro then thanks

Comment: if you'd like to use UDF, [here is one trick that can help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520732/i-dont-want-my-excel-add-in-to-return-an-array-instead-i-need-a-udf-to-change/8711582#8711582), (see @brettdj 's answer )

Answer (score 0):

Place this in any first row cell:
=MID($A$1,ROW(),1)

Answer (score 0):

I'm digging up a bit this subject but I have found a solution today as we now have the SEQUENCE formula:
=MID(A1,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(A1),1,1),1)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).