# Excel VBA custom function to set cell color

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function like so:

```
Function cellcolor(r As Range) As Long
  cellcolor = r.Interior.Color
End Function
```

I then reference it in Cell B1 like so:

```
=cellcolor(A1)
```

The color of A1 is red, and therefore the output is 255.

I want to set the color of B1 to match that of A1 but I'm unsure how.  Is it possible?

I've tried:

```
Function cellcolor(r As Range) As Long
  cellcolor.Interior.Color = r.Interior.Color
End Function
```

But it doesn't work, any ideas?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

As pointed out in the comments, a function cannot make cell format changes.  I therefore used the following:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Source As Range)

  For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each cell In ws.Range("B1")
      If Len(cell.Formula) > 0 Then
        cell.Interior.ColorIndex = Range(cell.Formula).Interior.ColorIndex
      End If
    Next cell
  Next ws

End Sub
```

Basically on cell change it finds which cell B1 is looking at, gets the target cell's color and copies it.  It does this across all sheets in the workbook.

I know it's a bit weird but serves it's purpose.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: The functions looks correct . Could you try changing `cellcolor.Interior.Color` to `Range("B1").Interior.Color` because at the moment it appears that you are trying to assign a color to the cellcolor variable which is a `long` value rather than a range

Comment: @izzymo which functions look correct? In the second example the OP is trying to assign a value to the `.Interior.Color` property of a Long, shouldn't that be raising a few alarm bells here? Pretty sure this is raising a compile-time error but the OP simply failed to include that information in their question. Lee, I'm guess you're receiving an `invalid qualifier` error in your second attempt? brett gets right to the point though, Used-Defined Functions can't really affect the worksheet in this manner.

Comment: @aiken good pick-up, fat fingered on my behalf! I meant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520732/i-dont-want-my-excel-add-in-to-return-an-array-instead-i-need-a-udf-to-change

Comment: Thanks guys! I didn't realise that functions can't change cell colors! I've added the fix into the original question.  Thanks again