# removing the function call using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to remove the function call after a value is returned.

for example:

```
function testFunc(x as integer)
testfunc = x
end function
```

after calling this function I would like the cell value where the function was called to equal x and not =testFunc(x).  Is this possible or do the limits placed on functions restrict this type of action

Comment: This is then being used as a formula and just like a formula you can always copy and paste only the value, after the formula returns a value.

Comment: But just to be clear this cannot be done in the function itself.

Comment: I am aware of the option to copy and paste just the value, but I am looking for a solution is handled within the function.  I am trying to make the function as simple to use as possible.  thank you for the input though

Answer (score 0):

Try this short macro:

```
End Function
Sub FunctionReplacer()
   Dim r As Range

   For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
      If InStr(1, LCase(r.Formula), "testfunc") > 0 Then
         r.Value = r.Value
      End If
   Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: while this works well it doesn't suit all my need. which is in no way your fault because I wasn't very clear.  I was looking for something that would work within the function so that extra steps would not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create a solution (not a very pretty or elegant one) using a workaround I found on [a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520732/i-dont-want-my-excel-add-in-to-return-an-array-instead-i-need-a-udf-to-change)

I used the code the link provided to allow myself to copy and paste simply the value using pastespecial